# Slow query on large table with GROUP BY and ORDER BY

Tags: postgresql, performance, index, sorting, group-by

I have a table with 7.2 million tuples which looks like this:

```
                               table public.methods
 column |          type         |                      attributes
--------+-----------------------+----------------------------------------------------
 id     | integer               | not null DEFAULT nextval('methodkey'::regclass)
 hash   | character varying(32) | not null
 string | character varying     | not null
 method | character varying     | not null
 file   | character varying     | not null
 type   | character varying     | not null
Indexes:
    "methods_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "methodhash" btree (hash)
```

Now I want to select some values but the query is incredibly slow:

```
db=# explain 
    select hash, string, count(method) 
    from methods 
    where hash not in 
          (select hash from nostring) 
    group by hash, string 
    order by count(method) desc;
                                            QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Sort  (cost=160245190041.10..160245190962.07 rows=368391 width=182)
   Sort Key: (count(methods.method))
   ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=160245017241.77..160245057764.73 rows=368391 width=182)
       ->  Sort  (cost=160245017241.77..160245026451.53 rows=3683905 width=182)
             Sort Key: methods.hash, methods.string
             ->  Seq Scan on methods  (cost=0.00..160243305942.27 rows=3683905 width=182)
                   Filter: (NOT (SubPlan 1))
                   SubPlan 1
                   ->  Materialize  (cost=0.00..41071.54 rows=970636 width=33)
                     ->  Seq Scan on nostring  (cost=0.00..28634.36 rows=970636 width=33)
```

The `hash` column is the md5 hash of `string` and has an index. So I think my problem is that the whole table is sorted by id and not by hash, so it takes a while to sort it first and then group it?

The table `nostring` contains only a list of hashes I don't want to have. But I need both tables to have all values. So it's not an option to delete these.

additional info: none of the columns can be null (fixed that in the table definition) and i'm using postgresql 9.2.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `LEFT JOIN` in [@dezso's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/29492/3684) should be good. An index, however, will hardly be useful (per se), because the query has to read the whole table anyway - the exception being index-only scans in Postgres 9.2+ and favorable conditions, see below.

```
SELECT m.hash, m.string, count(m.method) AS method_ct
FROM   methods m
LEFT   JOIN nostring n USING (hash)
WHERE  n.hash IS NULL
GROUP  BY m.hash, m.string 
ORDER  BY count(m.method) DESC;
```

Run `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` on the query. Several times to exclude cashing effects and noise. Compare the best results.

Create a multi-column index that matches your query:

```
CREATE INDEX methods_cluster_idx ON methods (hash, string, method);
```

Wait? After I said an index wouldn't help? Well, we need it to `CLUSTER` the table:

```
CLUSTER methods USING methods_cluster_idx;
ANALYZE methods;
```

Rerun `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. Any faster? It should be.

`CLUSTER` is a one-time operation to rewrite the whole table in the order of the used index. It is also effectively a `VACUUM FULL`. If you want to be sure, you'd run a pre-test with `VACUUM FULL` alone to see what can be attributed to that.

If your table sees a lot of write operations, the effect will degrade over time. Schedule `CLUSTER` at off-hours to restore the effect. Fine tuning depends of your exact use-case. [The manual about `CLUSTER`.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-cluster.html)

`CLUSTER` is a rather crude tool, needs an exclusive lock on the table. If you can't afford that, consider [`pg_repack`](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) which can do the same without exclusive lock. More in this later answer:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

---

**If** the percentage of `NULL` values in the column `method` is high (more than ~ 20 percent, depending on actual row sizes), a [**partial index**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-partial.html) should help:

```
CREATE INDEX methods_foo_idx ON methods (hash, string)
WHERE method IS NOT NULL;
```

<sub>(Your later update shows your columns to be `NOT NULL`, so not applicable.)</sub>

**If** you are running PostgreSQL **9.2** or later (as [@deszo commented](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/29489/slow-query-on-large-table-with-group-by-and-order-by/29564#comment51078_29564)) the presented indexes may be useful without `CLUSTER` if the planner can utilize **index-only scans**. Only applicable under favorable conditions: No write operations that would effect the visibility map since the last `VACUUM` and all columns in the query have to be covered by the index. Basically read-only tables can use this any time, while heavily written tables are limited. [More details in the Postgres Wiki.](http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/What%27s_new_in_PostgreSQL_9.2#Index-only_scans)

The above mentioned partial index could be even more useful in that case.

**If**, on the other hand, there are *no* `NULL` values in column `method`, you should
1.) define it `NOT NULL` and
2.) use `count(*)` instead of `count(method)`, that's slightly faster and does the same in the absence of `NULL` values.

**If** you have to call this query often and the table is read-only, create a [**`MATERIALIZED VIEW`**](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-creatematerializedview.html).

---

Exotic fine point:
Your table is named `nostring`, yet seems to contain hashes. By excluding hashes instead of strings, there is a chance that you exclude more strings than intended. *Extremely* unlikely, but possible.

Answer (score 5):

Welcome to DBA.SE!

You can try to rephrase your query like this:

```
SELECT m.hash, string, count(method) 
FROM 
    methods m
    LEFT JOIN nostring n ON m.hash = n.hash
WHERE n.hash IS NULL
GROUP BY hash, string 
ORDER BY count(method) DESC;
```

or another possibility:

```
SELECT m.hash, string, count(method) 
FROM 
    methods m
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT hash FROM nostring WHERE hash = m.hash)
GROUP BY hash, string 
ORDER BY count(method) DESC;
```

`NOT IN` is a typical sink for performance since it is hard to use an index with it.

This may be further enhanced with indexes.  An index on `nostring.hash` looks useful.  But first: what do you get now?  (It would be better to see the output of `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` since the costs themselves don't tell the time the operations took.)

Comment: The cost is only for the planner to be able to schoose a sufficiently good plan.  The actual times usually correlate with it, but not necessarily.  So if you want to be sure, use `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`.

Answer (score 1):

Since hash is an md5, you may probably try to convert it in a number: you may store it as a number, or just create a functional index that calculate that number in a immutable function.

Other people already created a pl/pgsql function that convert (part of) an md5 value from text to string. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809381/hashing-a-string-to-a-numeric-value-in-postgressql for an example

I believe that you are really spending a lot of time in string comparison while scanning the index. If you manage to store that value as a number, then it should be really really faster.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this issue a lot, and discovered a simple 2-part trick.

1. Create substring index on the hash value : (7 is usually a good length)

   `create index methods_idx_hash_substring ON methods(substring(hash,1,7))`
2. Have your searches/joins include a substring match, so the query planner is hinted to use the index:

   old:  `WHERE hash = :kwarg`

   new:  `WHERE (hash = :kwarg) AND (substring(hash,1,7) = substring(:kwarg,1,7))`

You should also have an index on the raw `hash` as well.

the result (usually) is that planner will consult the substring index first and weed out most of the rows.  then it matches the full 32 character hash to the corresponding index (or table).  this approach has dropped 800ms queries down to 4 for me.