# Query slows with additional FROM item (even with no extra actions)

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, join, count

I have a locally hosted table `comment` on Postgres 9.5 with ~ 2.6 million rows. When I run the following query, it executes in .867 ms:

```
SELECT COUNT(body)
FROM comment
WHERE body LIKE '%[deleted]%';
```

But the following query takes > 50 seconds (stopped measuring at this point):

```
SELECT COUNT(c1.body)
FROM comment c1, comment c2
WHERE c1.body LIKE '%[deleted]%';
```

I ask because I'm trying to implement a query like the following:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(c1.body)/COUNT(c2.body) as percent_deleted
FROM comment c1, comment c2
WHERE c1.body LIKE '%[deleted]%' 
AND c1.id = c2.id;
```

Comment: c1 and c2 refer to the same table.

Comment: why do you cross join with itself?

Comment: I've updated the op

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I understand if you want to know which is % of 'deleted' rows, do not cross join with the same table, get total rows and calculate the result on your initial query.

```
with totalc2 as 
(
    select count(*) nrows
    from comment
)
SELECT CAST(COUNT(c1.body) AS float) /totalc2.nrows) as percent_deleted
FROM comment c1
WHERE c1.body LIKE '%[deleted]%'
```

You can use it as a subquery:

```
SELECT CAST(COUNT(c1.body) AS float) / (select count(*) from comment) as percent_deleted
FROM comment c1
WHERE c1.body LIKE '%[deleted]%'
```

Comment: Ah, okay. I was wondering whether I could avoid using a with statement, but that'll work fine. Thanks for the help

Comment: (Made a small edit to add an "AS float" to your "CAST")

Comment: @joanolo I'm sorry I've misunderstood and edited it again, thanks

Comment: You can just cast once: float / integer is legal, and will return a float.

Answer (score 2):

#### Preface

The incorrect cross join in your original query produces an extremely expensive Cartesian product of 6760000000000 rows (2.6e6^2). The count takes a while, producing nonsense. Related:

- [What does [FROM x, y] mean in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/167201/what-does-from-x-y-mean-in-postgres/167217#167217)

And it has to be mentioned: there are better ways to mark deleted rows than concatenating the string '[deleted]' into a character column (not even at the begin or end of the string, no, *somewhere* in the string). Like ... basically *any* other way. But consider a `timestamptz` column named `deleted_at` with `now()` as default value.

#### Short solution

There is also the corner case of an empty table, which would result in a "division by zero". Use [`NULLIF()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-NULLIF) to (correctly) get NULL for this case.

```
SELECT round(count(body LIKE '%[deleted]%' OR NULL)::numeric
           / NULLIF(count(*), 0), 2) AS percent_deleted
FROM   comment;
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=ae1a42fb59d794c208da9a5a286e5ebc)*

Optionally, [`round()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html#FUNCTIONS-MATH-FUNC-TABLE) to round to *n* fractional digits (which demands `numeric`).

Related:

- [Need separate columns that calculate percentage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75345/need-separate-columns-that-calculate-percentage/75347#75347)
- [For absolute performance, is SUM faster or COUNT?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27558/for-absolute-performance-is-sum-faster-or-count/27572#27572)

#### Fast solution

Since you stress the performance of the query: there may be (much) faster solutions for your big table, depending on exact requirements and use case. If ...

1. Speed of this query is important / you run it a lot.
2. "deleted" rows are rare or rows are wide - which makes a partial index small when compared to the table.
3. We can assume a pretty good estimate for the total number of rows in the table statistics. That means:

   - autovacuum is running.
   - no substantial changes to the total row number in very short periods of time (large enough `INSERT` or `DELETE` that would actually change percentage until reflected in updated table statistics).

Then, this is good enough and many times faster. Create a partial index holding only "deleted" rows:

```
CREATE INDEX ON comments (comment_id) WHERE body LIKE '%[deleted]%';
```

The index column (`comment_id`) is irrelevant, might even be a constant `TRUE` or something. I added the PK column, because that's typically useful for other purposes and it typically does not change, making it comparatively cheap as index column.

Then this results in a very cheap index-only scan on above partial index, plus an even cheaper index scan on the system table `pg_class`:

```
SELECT round(count(*)::numeric
          / (SELECT NULLIF(reltuples, 0)::int
             FROM pg_class WHERE oid = 'comment'::regclass), 2) AS percent_deleted
FROM   comment
WHERE  body LIKE '%[deleted]%';
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c390a46cef46cfe2edc7832a0d035d28)*

Counting is relatively slow for *big* tables in Postgres, this can make a ***huge*** difference for getting a *low* percentage from a *big* table.

Related:

- [Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7943233/fast-way-to-discover-the-row-count-of-a-table-in-postgresql/7945274#7945274)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a simple *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(case when body LIKE '%[deleted]%' then 1 end)
 / COUNT(c2.body) as percent_deleted
FROM comment
```

Edit: As @joanolo commented you must either CAST one of the counts to a Float/Decimal to avoid integer arithmetic or multiply like this to get percentage:

```
SELECT
   100.00 * COUNT(case when body LIKE '%[deleted]%' then 1 end)
 / COUNT(c2.body) as percent_deleted
FROM comment
```

Comment: When using PostgreSQL, you would get an integer/integer division = 0. Other databases would make an implicit cast to float before making the division. In the case of PostgreSQL, the cast must be explicit.

Comment: Thanks for spotting, of course, this is Standard SQL behaviour, not just PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to optimize the query (to make sure your table is only scanned once), you can also do it this way:

```
SELECT
    (CAST(deleted_count AS float) / full_count) AS deleted_ratio
FROM
    (SELECT
         count(CASE WHEN body LIKE '%[deleted]%' THEN 1 END) AS deleted_count,
         count(*) AS full_count
     FROM
         comment
    ) AS q0 ;
```

You can check it at http://rextester.com/IMVFMF59176