# How can I get the percentage of the table the groups represent?

Tags: postgresql, query, count

Given a query like this,

```
CREATE TABLE foo(grp)
AS VALUES ('a'),('a'),('b'),('b'),('b'),('c'),('c'),('c'),('c'),('e');
```

I can use `GROUP BY` to aggregate into `a`,`b`,`c`,`e`, but how can I return the different groups, and the percentage of the total table they represent?

```
a | 20%
b | 30%
c | 40%
e | 10%
```

Comment: can you provide sample data?

Comment: Please **[Edit]** your question and add the `CREATE TABLE` statements for the tables in question adding the desired output. Those answering need a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Use [formatted text](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/124486).

Comment: @EvanCarroll Sorry, right now I modify the questiion.

Comment: no, i mean provide some sample data (no query)without the percentages and then tell us what you want it to read.

Comment: might help: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75345/need-separate-columns-that-calculate-percentage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First percentages are always in a range of `[0-1)` when stored on a computer. Rendering them in a range of a `0-100` is usually a function of the display (app). From wikipedia,

> For example, `45%` (read as "forty-five percent") is equal to 
>   `45 / 100`, `45:100`, or **`0.45`**.

If you have for example a simple table.

```
CREATE TABLE foo(grp)
AS VALUES ('a'),('a'),('b'),('b'),('b'),('c'),('c'),('c'),('c'),('e');
```

All you must do is

```
SELECT foo.grp, count(*) / tablestat.total::float AS percent_total
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS total FROM foo) AS tablestat
GROUP BY tablestat.total, foo.grp
ORDER BY grp;

 grp | percent_total 
-----+---------------
 a   |           0.2
 b   |           0.3
 c   |           0.4
 e   |           0.1
(4 rows)
```

Now if you want `percent` to be displayed like a string, you can easily do that too. Because it's mere visual display, I suggest not to do this in a database but we *can*; a function like this is simple and hides the obscuring details of how you want the number rendered, from the math that calculates it:

```
CREATE FUNCTION display_percent(x double precision)
RETURNS text
AS $$
  SELECT (x*100)::text || '%'
$$ LANGUAGE sql
IMMUTABLE;

COMMENT ON FUNCTION display_percent
  IS $$Render a number in the range of [0-1) as a text-string (ex., 0.17 to '17%')$$;
```

And there we have it,

```
SELECT foo.grp, display_percent(count(*) / tablestat.total::float) AS percent_total
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN (SELECT count(*) AS total FROM foo) AS tablestat
GROUP BY tablestat.total, foo.grp
ORDER BY grp;
 grp | percent_total 
-----+---------------
 a   | 20%
 b   | 30%
 c   | 40%
 e   | 10%
(4 rows)
```

Comment: Excuse me, what means 'tablestat'?

Comment: it's just a table alias (can be anything). that's a query that has a result set with one row, "count" that was generated from the `count(*)` on a specific table.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the from clause in your outer select

```
SELECT location,
        COUNT(*) AS total,
       (COUNT(*) * 100)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1) AS percentage
FROM table1 
WHERE extract(year from date) = 2018 GROUP BY location;
```

It would be better to do it as

```
WITH w_table_count AS (
    SELECT COUNT(0) AS table_count
    FROM table1
    )
SELECT t.location,
       t.count(t.date) AS TOTAL
       (count(t.date)/wt.table_count) * 100 AS percentage
FROM table1 t, w_table_count
WHERE extract(year from t.date) = 2018 GROUP BY t.location;
```

Comment: A CTE in PostreSQL is an optimization fence.