# Query to obtain weighted percentile

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, postgresql-10

Trying generate SQL to compute a weighted continuous value at a given set of percentile values (the 25%,50%,and 75% levels used below, but solution should allow for an arbitrary parameter level). In other words, want to find the interpolated "raw" values, weighted by "cnt", at each of the 25%, 50% and 75% cumulative percentiles for the test data in "source" table below.

*NB:* `cnt` represents the number of times that the `raw` value occurred during the sampling period, and the expected output would weight the `raw` value by `cnt` to arrive at the percentile (akin to quantile/ median and similar statistics)

**Test data:** (Table: source)

```
|  site  |  dateval   |  raw  |   cnt   |
+--------+------------+-------+---------+
|   A    | 2019-01-05 |   45  |      14 |
|   A    | 2019-01-05 |   52  |     178 |
|   A    | 2019-01-05 |   45  |       9 |
|   A    | 2019-01-05 |   37  |      75 |
|   A    | 2019-01-05 |   23  |      98 |
|   A    | 2019-01-05 |   78  |     102 |
|   A    | 2019-01-05 |   56  |       9 |
|   A    | 2019-01-05 |   17  |      54 |
|   A    | 2019-01-05 |   56  |       8 |
|   A    | 2019-01-06 |   33  |      35 |
|   A    | 2019-01-06 |   67  |      45 |
|   A    | 2019-01-06 |   65  |      93 |
|   A    | 2019-01-06 |   89  |     113 |
|   A    | 2019-01-06 |   52  |      64 |
|   A    | 2019-01-06 |  101  |      12 |
|   B    | 2019-01-05 |    5  |      25 |
|   B    | 2019-01-05 |   16  |      48 |
|   B    | 2019-01-05 |   12  |     107 |
|   B    | 2019-01-05 |   25  |      78 |
|   B    | 2019-01-05 |   44  |      53 |
|   B    | 2019-01-05 |    8  |      12 |
|   B    | 2019-01-05 |   31  |      32 |
|   B    | 2019-01-06 |   34  |      87 |
|   B    | 2019-01-06 |   18  |      35 |
|   B    | 2019-01-06 |   51  |      17 |
|   B    | 2019-01-06 |   22  |      23 |
|   B    | 2019-01-06 |   14  |      52 |
|   B    | 2019-01-06 |    6  |      34 |
+--------+------------+-------+---------+
```

**Expected output** (rounded to nearest 1/100th):

```
|  site  |   dateval  |   p00   |   p25   |   p50   |   p75   |   p100  |
+--------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
|   A    | 2019-01-05 |   17.00 |   22.07 |   45.92 |   51.30 |   78.00 |
|   A    | 2019-01-06 |   33.00 |   49.48 |   63.46 |   73.72 |  101.00 |
|   B    | 2019-01-05 |    5.00 |    9.93 |   14.79 |   24.57 |   44.00 |
|   B    | 2019-01-06 |    6.00 |   10.31 |   18.52 |   27.79 |   51.00 |
+--------+------------+---------+---------+---------+---------+---------+
```

*NB*: The above results assume linear smoothing between `raw` values. For instance, the `p25`value of `22.07` `=` `[ (25.00% - 54/547) / ((98+54)/547 - 54/547) ] * (23-17) + 17`, where `547 = sum(cnt) | site='A' & dateval='2019-01-05'`.

**Current SQL**

The below computes percentile values at discreet points, based on the "raw" values present in table "source." However, the desired output is the "raw" value that corresponds to a given percentile on a continuous basis (for simplicity, the interpolation between discreet "raw" levels is linear instead of splines/other). Frankly, not sure the following approach is the most appropriate path:

```
WITH raw_lvl AS (
  SELECT "site", "dateval", "raw", sum("cnt") AS "sumcnt"
  FROM   source
  GROUP BY "site", "dateval", "raw"
), cum_raw AS (
  SELECT tlr.*, sum(tlr."sumcnt") OVER "win_cr" AS "cumsumcnt"
  FROM raw_lvl AS "tlr"
  WINDOW "win_cr" AS (PARTITION BY tlr."site", tlr."dateval" ORDER BY tlr."raw" ASC)
)
SELECT cr.*, cr."cumsumcnt"/(sum(cr."sumcnt") OVER "win_pr") AS "percentile" 
FROM cum_raw AS cr
WINDOW "win_pr" AS (PARTITION BY cr."site", cr."dateval");
```

Postgres version 10.3

Comment: `weighted by "cnt"` - weighted *how* exactly?

Comment: Thank you for the clarifying question. `cnt` represents the number of times that the `raw` value occurred during the sampling period, and the `raw` value would be weighted by `cnt` to arrive at the percentile (akin to quantile/ median and similar statistics). I believe your proposed answer interprets the expected weighting to the original question. Thx & will update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Postgres has [**Ordered-Set Aggregate Functions**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html#FUNCTIONS-ORDEREDSET-TABLE) for your purpose.

The special difficulty: you want rows "weighted" by `cnt`. If that's supposed to mean that each row represents `cnt` identical rows, you can multiply input rows by joining to `generate_series(1, cnt)`:

```
SELECT site, dateval
     , percentile_cont('{0,.25,.5,.75,1}'::float8[]) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY raw)
FROM   source s, generate_series(1, s.cnt)
GROUP  BY 1, 2;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=1da2ed1cdb90c2bd0acea44fc0ce24fd)*

But results differ from your expected output (except for the 0 and 100 percentile). So you are "weighting" differently ...

Aside, your original query can be simplified to this equivalent:

```
SELECT site, dateval, raw, sum(cnt) AS sumcnt
     , sum(sum(cnt)) OVER w AS cumsumcnt
     , sum(sum(cnt)) OVER w / sum(sum(cnt)) OVER (PARTITION BY site, dateval) AS percentile 
FROM   source
GROUP  BY site, dateval, raw
WINDOW w AS (PARTITION BY site, dateval ORDER BY raw);
```

You can run a window function over the result of an aggregate function in the same `SELECT` (but not vice versa). See:

- [Need separate columns that calculate percentage](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75345/need-separate-columns-that-calculate-percentage/75347#75347)

I added a demo to the fiddle above.

But neither explains the odd numbers in your "expected results". Those strike me as incorrect, no matter how you interpolate. Example: `22.07` in the first line for `p25` does not seem to make sense - the value `23` occupies all rows up to the `27.7879` percentile after factoring in `cnt` according to your own query ...

Comment: Thank you, and this is the more elegant approach that gets _close_ to the desired result! However, no interpolation appears to occur (ie. the proposed SQL appears to behave the same as `percentile_disc(...)` whereby the `raw` value that is equal to, or greater than, the percentile cut-off is output  [at least on my machine -- can test proof of concept by replacing `percentile_cont(...)` with `percentile_disc(...)`]. I (wildly) speculate that this occurs from the interaction with `generate_series(...)`. Any thoughts to adapt proposal to perform the interpolation of continuous points?

Comment: @Whee: Interpolation *does* occur - but only if a given percentile falls between two distinct values. Look at my simple additions in the fiddle. It's still not clear to me how you arrive at your "expected results". I added some more above.

Comment: Spent time noodling on this (and a sincere thank you for the time). I see where interpolation _does_ occur (iff percentile falls between discreet, differing `raw` values) as you mention (sorry I missed this in the fiddle the first time). I am going to expand on the "Expected Output" section to the question to describe the approach -- in short, the raw data (and current answer) fit step functions with multiple occurrences at each level, but the (additional?) "interpolation" sought is to smooth the "jumps" between each `raw` level (the "Expected Output" uses a simple linear approach).

Comment: Marking this as answer. I was able to interpolate through the levels using `generate_series(...)` across each level weighting and using the ratio of the series over the cumulative weight over the interval to define more granular interpretation points. Thank you again for the time.

Answer (score 0):

Use the sum() over function can help, the percentile index is in column

```
select * from 
( select site, dateval, raw, 1 / cum_cnt_ratio as percentile,
row_number() over(partition by site, dateval, cum_cnt_ratio order by cum_cnt_mod asc) as cum_mod_rank
from 
(select 
t1.site, t1.dateval, raw, 
floor(cum_cnt / all_cnt / 0.25) as cum_cnt_ratio, 
mod(cum_cnt / all_cnt, 0.25) as cum_cnt_mod
from
(select site, dateval, sum(cnt) as all_cnt 
FROM source
group by site, dateval ) t1
join 
( select 
site, dateval,
raw,
sum(cnt) over(partition by site, dateval order by raw) as cum_cnt
from source
) t2 
on(t1.site = t2.site and t1.dateval = t2.dataval)
) t3
) t4
where cum_mod_rank = 1
```