# Replace multiple columns with single JSON column

Tags: postgresql, json, row

I am running PostgreSQL 9.3.4. I have a table with 3 columns:

| id | name | addr |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | n1 | ad1 |
| 2 | n2 | ad2 |

I need to move the data to a new table with a JSON column like:

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"name": "n1", "addr": "ad1"} |
| 2 | {"name": "n2", "addr": "ad2"} |

I tried:

```
SELECT t.id, row_to_json(t) AS data
FROM (SELECT id, name, addr FROM myt) t;
```

But that includes `id` in the result. So `row_to_json` is not the solution for me.

Is there a way to get only the columns I need (`name` & `addr`)?

Comment: I am not sure if the answer is correct. I asked it 2 years ago. I also answered my question back then but didn't mark it as correct.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the answer from [this link](http://hashrocket.com/blog/posts/faster-json-generation-with-postgresql):

```
select * from (
  select id,
    (
      select row_to_json(d)
      from (
        select name, addr
        from myt d
        where d.id=s.id
      ) d
    ) as data
  from myt s
)
```

Comment: Dont' forget to mark your own answer as correct (no points though :-( ). I don't think that you can do this immediately, but it might help someone with a similar question in the future.

Comment: Aside from the missing table alias in the outer query, this is also more complex and expensive than necessary. I added another answer with a fiddle to demonstrate.

Comment: Does this build an object array instead of returning duplicate outer query results?

Answer (score 100):

Simplest with the operator [`jsonb - text → jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) to remove a single key in **Postgres 9.5** or later - after converting the whole row with [`to_jsonb()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE). (Cast the result to `json` if you don't want `jsonb`.)

```
SELECT id, to_jsonb(t.*) - 'id' AS data
FROM   myt t;
```

In **Postgres 10** or later, you can also remove a whole array of keys with the [operator `jsonb - text[] → jsonb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE).

There is also a better option with [**`json_build_object()`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) in **Postgres 9.4** or later:

```
SELECT id, json_build_object('name', name, 'addr', addr) AS data
FROM   myt;
```

But there is an even simpler way since **Postgres 9.3**:

```
SELECT id, to_json((SELECT d FROM (SELECT name, addr) d)) AS data
FROM   myt;
```

[`to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE) is mostly the same as [`row_to_json()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-CREATION-TABLE).
Find a couple more syntax variants in the fiddle.

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=04b3017aeebd0f1578b6abb135776aa0)*
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/0c372/3) (Postgres 9.6)</sub>

Related answers:

- [Select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/postgresql-select-columns-inside-json-agg/69658#69658)
- [Return as array of JSON objects in SQL (Postgres)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26486910/939860)
- [Return total number of rows and selected (aggregated) data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84322/return-total-number-of-rows-and-selected-aggregated-data/84376#84376)

Comment: This is a better answer, and the fiddle has the proof.

Comment: another banger from Erwin, i'm your biggest fan