# Build array from boolean columns

Tags: postgresql, array, unpivot

I have columns like `role1`, `role2`, `role3`, etc. They are all booleans.

I would like to create a view on this table, that has a roles column of type `text[]`. If the columns were `TRUE, FALSE, TRUE`, the view would contain `["role1", "role3"]`.

Is there any good way to do this that doesn't explode into a ton of `CASE WHEN`´s? To clarify, I'd be fine with O(n) with `CASE WHEN`, but not O(2^n) which is what it currently seems to need. :)

Comment: More often than not, incrementally numbered columns are a symptom of a bad database design and indicate that the table should be split up in a proper one-to-many relationship

Comment: Yes. The columns are not actually named numbers, they're actual role names that I didn't want to disclose.

Comment: That still sounds like a de-normalized model

Comment: Yeah I know. I'm on the Heroku free tier for Postgres which limits me to 10,000 rows. I would normally make a "role <-> user" many to many table, but that would skyrocket past 10k rows since, the average user has more than 1 role and there's over 2500 users.

Comment: In that case it might be easier to store that in a single `text[]` column directly

Comment: That wouldn't prevent duplicates though. Granting a role is a common operation, and I'm not really sure how that would work. "update users set role1=true where id=?" is pretty simple, and it wouldn't really have an equivalent that I can see... Maybe something like "update users set roles=append(roles, 'role1') where id=? and roles does not contain 'role1'". But now there's a second query to see if the user existed in the first place, because we want to error out if they didn't exist, but not error out if they exist but already had the role. Maybe a transaction? idk

Comment: If you want to ensure uniqueness a JSONB column with key/value pairs might be another option: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=a6462335d45581a03494c3fbc1223171 or using a JSONB array: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b8656005d53358db2253a4eb6a381ffb (which uses less space)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest a `VALUES` expression in the lateral subquery.

```
SELECT t.id, a.roles
FROM   tbl t
CROSS  JOIN LATERAL (
   SELECT ARRAY(
      SELECT col
      FROM  (
         VALUES
            ('role1', role1) -- eligible columns
          , ('role2', role2)
          , ('role3', role3)
         ) x(col, val)
      WHERE  val
     )
  ) a(roles);
```

This "unpivots" columns to rows, so we can process a set instead of a row.

As [a_horse demonstrates](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/260354/3684), `json`(`b`) is versatile enough to also cover this task. And you don't need to spell out eligible columns while all `boolean` columns are processed. But it seems you have to spell out eligible columns anyway.

Subtle difference: this returns an empty array for "no qualifying values" (`{}`), while a_horse's query returns `NULL` for the same.

This should be **substantially faster** for three reasons:

1. Only processes eligible columns to begin with. Especially relevant with many additional (possibly big?) columns.
2. Involves less casting back and forth and the predicate is as cheap as it gets.
3. ARRAY constructor is faster than `array_agg()`. See:

   - [Why is array_agg() slower than the non-aggregate ARRAY() constructor?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/159710/why-is-array-agg-slower-than-the-non-aggregate-array-constructor/159717#159717)

Or, simpler yet: plain `CASE` expressions concatenated with `concat_ws()`. If a string is good enough:

```
SELECT t.id
     , concat_ws(','
               , CASE WHEN role1 THEN 'role1' END -- eligible columns
               , CASE WHEN role2 THEN 'role2' END
               , CASE WHEN role3 THEN 'role3' END) AS roles_string
FROM   tbl t;
```

Should be the fastest possible solution. And not that much more verbose. See:

- [How to concatenate columns in a Postgres SELECT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19943343/939860)
- [Combine two columns and add into one new column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12320369/939860)

Or to get the same array as above:

```
SELECT t.id
     , string_to_array(
          concat_ws(
             ','
           , CASE WHEN role1 THEN 'role1' END -- eligible columns
           , CASE WHEN role2 THEN 'role2' END
           , CASE WHEN role3 THEN 'role3' END)
        , ',') AS roles
FROM   tbl t;
```

We can also generate the list of eligible columns dynamically from the the system catalogs. (If you don't want to spell out columns after all.)

Or narrow down to eligible columns for the `json`(`b`) technique to eliminate possibly expensive noise early. See:

- [Postgres multiple columns to json](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90858/postgres-multiple-columns-to-json/90871#90871)

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=076f65ee82b8a510a11321bad4b0e081)* - incl. all of the above, a_horse's jsonb query, and a couple of variants

Comment: @lurf jurv: I would be interested how the query variants actually perform in your case (plus row count and the number & nature of columns). Can you compare with `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE)`?

Comment: Thank you so much! This is 21 times faster :)

I've done the explain analyze on my actual table. It isn't that big, only 2000 rows, but it's still pretty consistent times. I ran each explain analyze about five times, there was only a few % of variance. https://pastebin.com/XBgdXUwn

Comment: https://github.com/ImpactDevelopment/ImpactServer/commit/07dcdef85152f3c29f72b2afe43a33973e8c6b87

Comment: Oh, and one last thing, I also just now tried explain analyze with removing the string_to_array, and it takes it from 1.9ms to 1.1ms. It is only this slow because this is on Heroku's free Postgres tier :)

I will keep it with the array though because it makes the code that reads the roles list more reasonable.

Thanks again for doing this!

Answer (score 4):

You can convert the row to a JSON value and then use a sub-select:

```
select t.id, x.roles
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
     select array_agg(col) as roles
     from jsonb_each_text(to_jsonb(t)) x(col,val)
     where x.val::boolean
       and x.col like 'role%'
  ) x
```

Comment: This worked! However, I had to change up the x.col. Otherwise, it failed trying to coerce an earlier column to boolean. So my query looks like "where x.col=any('{foo,bar,baz}') and x.val='true'"