# How can I return multiple columns from an array of ids?

Tags: postgresql, query, json, array

I have a two tables like the following:

```
workshops table
+----+--------------+------------+
| id |     name     | option_ids |
+----+--------------+------------+
|  1 | Conversation | {2,3}      |
+----+--------------+------------+

options table
+----+-----------+---------------+
| id |    day    |     time      |
+----+-----------+---------------+
|  1 | Monday    | 13:00 - 14:00 |
|  2 | Tuesday   | 12:00 - 13:00 |
|  3 | Wednesday | 11:00 - 12:00 |
+----+-----------+---------------+
```

I want to construct a Query where I retrieve the workshop name and also all the information for option_ids 2 and 3.

I would like to eventually construct a JSON like so:

```
{
    name: "Conversation",
    options: [
        { day: "Tuesday", time: "12:00 - 13:00" }, 
        { day: "Wednesday", time: "11:00 - 12:00" }
    ]

}
```

Looking at the postgresql.org documentation maybe it has something to do with the `json_object` function?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few build-in functions like this query:

```
select json_build_object(
   'name', w.name, 
   'options', (
       select json_agg(json_build_object('day', o.day, 'time', o.time))       
       from options o 
       where o.id =any(w.option_ids)  -- I am assuming option_ids is an array, not string
   )
) as result 
from workshops w;
```

will build a json like this:

```
 {"name" : "Conversation", "options" : [{"day" : "Tuesday", "time" : "12:00 - 13:00"}, {"day" : "Wednesday", "time" : "11:00 - 12:00"}]}
```

Comment: Nice! Just what I needed! Further question: is it possible to construct the 'options' property automatically by all column names? Instead of json_buid_object('day', o.day) could I just supply the row and construct all the property names by column? I have like seven columns that I want to include in that property but I would prefer not to write every single column manually.

Comment: We have `to_json` and `row_to_json` functions. If you need all columns from options table - then `select array_agg(row_to_json(o)) from options o`

Comment: Can be simplified to `SELECT json_agg(o) FROM options s`. Returns a JSON array as type `json` as opposed to `json[]`. Either works for the task ...

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to construct the 'options' property automatically by all column names?

Yes:

```
SELECT row_to_json(w) AS workshop
FROM  (
   SELECT w.name, (SELECT json_agg(o) FROM options o WHERE o.id = ANY(w.option_ids)) AS options
   FROM   workshops w
   ) w;
```

Notably, "all" means all columns from table `options`, including `id`.
To include only select columns like in your original question:

```
SELECT row_to_json(w) AS workshop
FROM  (
   SELECT w.name, (SELECT json_agg(o) FROM (
                      SELECT o.day, o.time FROM options o
                      WHERE  o.id = ANY(w.option_ids)
                      ) o
                  ) AS options
   FROM   workshops w
   ) w
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f8941f89919e539802ac152b3ed06fbc)*

Both work for Postgres 9.3 or later. `json_build_object()` was added with Postgres 9.4. See:

- [Select columns inside json_agg](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69655/select-columns-inside-json-agg/69658#69658)
- [Postgres multiple columns to json](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/90858/postgres-multiple-columns-to-json/90871#90871)

Answer (score 1):

Question: Will you ***ever*** query this data by option_id[s]?

If the answer to this question might [ever] be "Yes", then your data structure is wrong.
Holding *lists* of values in a *single* field is generally accepted to be Bad Practice.  Sure, there *are* functions that allow you to work with lists of values, but they will be **slow** compared to properly normalised data:

```
select * from workshops ; 

+----+--------------+
| id |     name     |
+----+--------------+
|  1 | Conversation |
+----+--------------+

select * from options ; 

+----+-----------+---------------+
| id |    day    |     time      |
+----+-----------+---------------+
| 11 | Monday    | 13:00 - 14:00 |
| 22 | Tuesday   | 12:00 - 13:00 |
| 33 | Wednesday | 11:00 - 12:00 |
+----+-----------+---------------+

select * from workshop_options ; 

+-------------+-----------+
| workshop_id | option_id | 
+-------------+-----------+
|           1 |        22 | 
|           1 |        33 |
+-------------+-----------+
```

The data for constructing your JSON starts from here:

```
select 
  w.name
, o.day
, o.time 
from workshops w 
inner join workshop_options wo 
      on w.id = wo.workshop_id 
inner join options o 
      on wo.option_id = o.id 
order by 1, 2, 3 ; 

+--------------+-----------+---------------+
| name         | day       | time          |
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
| Conversation | Tuesday   | 12:00 - 13:00 |
| Conversation | Wednesday | 11:00 - 12:00 |
+--------------+-----------+---------------+
```