# Nested aggregate functions over different dimensions

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, window-functions, postgresql-9.6

I have a table where I periodically record the throughput of all network interfaces on a set of servers:

```
create table net (
    ts timestamptz not null,
    host text not null,
    interface text not null,
    recv_bytes bigint not null
);
create index on net (ts);
insert into net (ts, host, interface, recv_bytes) values
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:00+00', 'a', 'eth0',  500),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:00+00', 'b', 'eth1', 2000),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:01+00', 'b', 'eth0', 1000),  -- measurements arrive with some jitter, +1s here
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:02+00', 'c', 'eth0',  100),  -- only present in this interval
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:04+00', 'b', 'eth1', 1900),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:05+00', 'a', 'eth0',  550),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:05+00', 'b', 'eth0', 1200),

    ('2017-01-01 00:00:10+00', 'a', 'eth0',  600),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:10+00', 'b', 'eth0', 1500),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:11+00', 'b', 'eth1', 1900),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:15+00', 'a', 'eth0',  600),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:15+00', 'b', 'eth1', 1400),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:16+00', 'b', 'eth0', 1400),
    ('2017-01-01 00:00:16+00', 'b', 'eth1', 1700);  -- (b,eth1) appears 3 times in this interval
```

I would like to find the total throughput across all interfaces for a given time range, averaged over 10 second intervals. If a (host, interface) pair is missing data for a given interval, it can simply be omitted. This is what I came up with:

```
select ts_interval, host, sum(recv_bytes) as recv_bytes
from (
    select
        to_timestamp(floor(extract(epoch from ts) / 10) * 10) as ts_interval,
        host,
        interface,
        avg(recv_bytes) as recv_bytes
    from net
    group by ts_interval, host, interface
) avg_net
where ts_interval >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00+00' and ts_interval < '2017-01-01 00:00:20+00'
group by ts_interval, host
order by ts_interval, host;
```

Result:

```
      ts_interval       | host |      recv_bytes
------------------------+------+-----------------------
 2017-01-01 00:00:00+00 | a    |  525.0000000000000000
 2017-01-01 00:00:00+00 | b    | 3050.0000000000000000
 2017-01-01 00:00:00+00 | c    |  100.0000000000000000
 2017-01-01 00:00:10+00 | a    |  600.0000000000000000
 2017-01-01 00:00:10+00 | b    | 3116.6666666666666667
```

This query seems overly verbose. The essence of that I'm trying to do is to sum over one dimension and average over the other. In pseudo-SQL:

```
select
    to_timestamp(floor(extract(epoch from ts) / 10) * 10) as ts_interval,
    host,
    sum(avg(recv_bytes OVER ts_interval) OVER host) as recv_bytes
from net
where ts >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00+00' and ts < '2017-01-01 00:00:20+00'
group by ts_interval, host
order by ts_interval, host;
```

Is there a more concise way to do this?

Comment: Very clear question with just the right amount of useful information. (Only your version of Postgres is missing.)

Comment: @Erwin Whoops, I'm on Postgres 9.6. I added the version as a tag just now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Query

You can use [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-srf.html) to generate a time raster to join to:

```
SELECT g AS ts_interval, host, sum(recv_bytes) AS recv_bytes
FROM  (
   SELECT g, host, interface, avg(recv_bytes) AS recv_bytes
   FROM   generate_series(timestamptz '2017-01-01 00:00:00+00'
                        , timestamptz '2017-01-01 00:00:10+00'  -- 10 - only lower bound
                        , interval '10 sec') g
   JOIN   net n ON ts >= g
               AND ts <  g + interval '10 sec'
   GROUP  BY g, host, interface
   ) sub
GROUP  BY g, host
ORDER  BY g, host;
```

Same result. Not less verbose, but *much* faster if you have an index on `(ts)`.

Then again, the crucial point is to have "[sargable](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sargable)" predicates, which you also get without `generate_series()` this way:

```
SELECT ts_interval, host, sum(recv_bytes) as recv_bytes
FROM  (
   SELECT to_timestamp(trunc(extract(epoch from ts) / 10) * 10) AS ts_interval
        , host, interface, avg(recv_bytes) as recv_bytes
   FROM   net
   WHERE  ts >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00+00'
   AND    ts <  '2017-01-01 00:00:20+00' -- just make sure to match bounds
   GROUP  BY 1, 2, 3
   ) avg_net
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

Minor point: With exclusively positive numbers, `trunc()` is equivalent to `floor()` and a bit faster.

I am using ordinal numbers, since you asked for "less verbose" code. But that's not the core of the question here ...

#### Core question

You *can* run a window function over an aggregate function in one query level (though it's not typically faster than using a subquery).

But not the other way round: you *cannot* run an aggregate function over a window function in one query level. Just not possible. Window functions happen *after* aggregate functions in SQL.
Related:

- [Best way to get result count before LIMIT was applied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156114/best-way-to-get-result-count-before-limit-was-applied/8242764#8242764)
- [How do I get the aggregate of a window function in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46297/how-do-i-get-the-aggregate-of-a-window-function-in-postgres/46304#46304)
- [Return total number of rows and selected (aggregated) data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84322/return-total-number-of-rows-and-selected-aggregated-data/84376#84376)
- [How will the order of operations in this query affect my results?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/54477/how-will-the-order-of-operations-in-this-query-affect-my-results/54565#54565)

Comment: I've never heard the term "time raster." As someone who works in GIS, I'm used to "raster" specifically referring to pixel based data formats. Everything on the first page of Google for "time raster" seems to be GIS related, as well. Do you have any links explaining what you mean by the term?

Comment: @jpmc26: That's just the wording I came up with, not a technical term. Maybe "time grid", "time series" or "time pattern" are less distracting.

Answer (score 2):

If there is limited amount of interfaces then it could be

```
select
  to_timestamp(floor(extract(epoch from ts) / 10) * 10) as ts_interval,
  host,
  coalesce(avg(recv_bytes) filter (where interface = 'eth0'), 0) + 
  coalesce(avg(recv_bytes) filter (where interface = 'eth1'), 0) +
  coalesce(avg(recv_bytes) filter (where interface = 'wlan0'), 0) -- etc
from
  net
group by 1,2
order by 1,2;
```

But I'm not sure that it is really better then the your original query.