# Add cumulative sum to time-series query PostgreSQL 9.5

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, running-totals, time-series-database

I wrote the query that gives me time-series over some date range and interval that shows revenue for each time interval:

```
SELECT
    interval_date,
    coalesce(campaign_revenue,0) AS campaign_revenue,
FROM
    -- generate_series helps fill the empty gaps in the following JOIN
    generate_series(
        $2::timestamp,
        $3::timestamp,
        $4) AS interval_date -- could be '1 day', '1 hour' or '1 minute'.
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    -- This SELECT gets all timeseries rows that have data
    (SELECT
        date_trunc($4, s.created) AS interval,
        SUM(s.revenue) campaign_revenue
    FROM
        sale_event AS s
    WHERE
        s.campaignid = $1 AND s.created BETWEEN $2 AND $3 AND s.event_type = 'session_closed'
    GROUP BY
        interval) results
ON
    (results.interval = interval_date);
```

The query takes every row of `sale_event` table, truncates the created date to some interval (aligns the `created` timestamp with the time-series wanted granularity), groups by this time interval and sums up the `revenue` columns on the rows where `event_type` is `session_closed`.

This works very well and gives me the revenue in the specified interval. The result may look like:

```
interval_date   |   campaign_revenue
------------------------------------
 2018-08-05     |   0.0
 2018-08-06     |   1.5
 2018-08-07     |   0.0
 2018-08-08     |   0.5
 2018-08-09     |   1.0
```

When the provided range is `2018-08-05 - 2018-08-09` and `interval = '1 day'`.

I want to add to the result the sum of revenue up to that date. So if before `2018-08-05` there a total revenue of `10.0`, the result would be:

```
interval_date   |   campaign_revenue   |   total_campaign_revenue
-----------------------------------------------------------------
 2018-08-05     |   0.0                |   10.0
 2018-08-06     |   1.5                |   11.5
 2018-08-07     |   0.0                |   11.5
 2018-08-08     |   0.5                |   12.0
 2018-08-09     |   1.0                |   13.0
```

Comment: How is the 10$ calculated, can we assume it is a constant?

Comment: Not a constant. The `10.0` would be the sum of all `sales_event.revenue` up to and including `2018-08-05`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get it right you can just add a window function outside of your query like:

```
SELECT interval_date, campaign_revenue
     , SUM(campaign_revenue) OVER (ORDER BY interval_date) 
      + (SELECT SUM(revenue) 
         FROM sale_event
         WHERE s.campaignid = $1
           AND s.created < $2
           AND s.event_type = 'session_closed') as total_campaign_revenue
FROM (
    SELECT interval_date
         , coalesce(campaign_revenue,0) AS campaign_revenue
    FROM
        -- generate_series helps fill the empty gaps in the following JOIN
        ...
        interval) results
    ON (results.interval = interval_date)
);
```

Another option is to apply the window function directly, and use a FILTER clause for `campaign_revenue`

Comment: Great, I will give it a go and update with the results! Do you think it should impact performance heavily, beyond the need to traverse the rows up to the first date in the range?

Comment: My guess is that the sub-select for earlier revenues will have the heaviest cost, but the best way to find out is to look at the execution plan and compare.

Answer (score 4):

It's typically faster to read all relevant rows from the underlying table in a single scan.
You can run a window function over an aggregate function in the same `SELECT`.

Test with [`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, TIMING OFF)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) to verify it's actually faster:

```
SELECT interval_ts
     , coalesce(revenue      , 0) AS campaign_revenue
     , coalesce(total_revenue, 0) AS total_campaign_revenue    
FROM   generate_series($2::timestamp, $3::timestamp, $4) AS interval_ts
LEFT   JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc($4, created) AS interval_ts
        , sum(revenue)                                              AS revenue
        , sum(sum(revenue)) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc($4, created)) AS total_revenue
   FROM   sale_event AS s
   WHERE  campaignid = $1
   AND    created <= $3                   -- read all relevant rows in one scan
   AND    event_type = 'session_closed'
   GROUP  BY date_trunc($4, created)
   ) results USING (interval_ts);
```

The `JOIN` excludes leading surplus rows in the subquery automatically.

`sum(sum(revenue)) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc($4, created))` works because, [quoting the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-WINDOW-FUNCTIONS):

> The default framing option is `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING`, which is the
> same as `RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW`. With `ORDER BY`, this sets the frame to be all rows from the partition start up
> through the current row's last `ORDER BY` peer.

Exactly what you need.

Related:

- [Calculating Cumulative Sum in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22843199/939860)
- [PostgreSQL: running count of rows for a query 'by minute'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8194088/939860)
- [How do I get the aggregate of a window function in Postgres?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46297/how-do-i-get-the-aggregate-of-a-window-function-in-postgres/46304#46304)

**Remaining weakness:** The total is missing for intervals with no revenue. If that's not acceptable, we can use this technique to fix:

- [Carry over long sequence of missing values with Postgres](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/186218/carry-over-long-sequence-of-missing-values-with-postgres/186244#186244)

```
SELECT interval_ts, campaign_revenue, total_revenue
     , coalesce(first_value(total_revenue) OVER (PARTITION BY grp ORDER BY interval_ts), 0) AS total_campaign_revenue    
FROM  (
   SELECT interval_ts
        , coalesce(revenue, 0) AS campaign_revenue
        , total_revenue
        , count(total_revenue) OVER (ORDER BY interval_ts) AS grp
   FROM  (
      SELECT interval_ts
           , coalesce(revenue, 0) AS campaign_revenue
           , count(total_revenue) OVER (ORDER BY interval_ts) AS grp
      FROM   generate_series($2::timestamp, $3::timestamp, $4) AS interval_ts
      LEFT   JOIN (
         SELECT date_trunc($4, created) AS interval_ts
              , sum(revenue) AS revenue
              , sum(sum(revenue)) OVER (ORDER BY date_trunc($4, created)) AS total_revenue
         FROM   sale_event AS s
         WHERE  campaignid = $1
         AND    created <= $3                   -- read all relevant rows in one scan
         AND    event_type = 'session_closed'
         GROUP  BY date_trunc($4, created)
         ) results USING (interval_ts)
      ) sub1
   ) sub2;
```

With the added overhead, I am not sure it can compete. Still might if your selection is small and the table is big.

Minor notes:

- You don't need parentheses around join conditions.
- Don't call your *timestamp* "date". That's misleading. I use `interval_ts` instead of `interval_date`.
- I'd rather not use the [SQL keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) `interval` as column alias - even if that's allowed in Postgres.
- Working with the same column alias `interval_ts` to allow the shorter `USING` syntax - which *does* require parentheses. This only exposes *one* instance of the joined columns `interval_ts` to the outer query, so the unqualified name still isn't ambiguous.
- Don't omit the `AS` key word for column aliases (while that's OK for table aliases).