# What is the overhead for varchar(n)?

Tags: postgresql, varchar, database-internals

I wanted to ask for the meaning of this fragment from [Postgres doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/interactive/datatype-character.html) regarding `varchar(n)` type:

> The storage requirement for a short string (up to 126 bytes) is 1 byte
>   plus the actual string, which includes the space padding in the case
>   of character. Longer strings have 4 bytes of overhead instead of 1.

Let's assume that I have a `varchar(255)` field. And now, the following statements:

- If this field holds a string of 10 bytes, then the overhead is 1 byte. So the string will use 11 bytes.
- If the field holds string using 140 bytes, then the overhead is 4 bytes. So the string will use 144 bytes.

Are those statements above true? [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18115470/1961303) someone understands the doc the same way as me but here someone states the overhead is always 4 bytes [here](http://www.postgresql.org/message-id/1079568455.12785.3.camel@ws12.commsecure.com.au)?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Unsurprisingly, the manual is right. But there is more to it.

For one, size ***on disk*** (in any *table*, even when not actually stored on disk) can be different from size ***in memory***. On disk, the overhead for short `varchar` values up to 126 bytes is reduced to a **1 byte** as stated in the manual. But the overhead **in memory is always 4 bytes** (once individual values are extracted).

The same is true for [`text`, `varchar`, `varchar(n)` or `char(n)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-character.html) - except that `char(n)` is blank-padded to `n` characters and you normally don't want to use it. Its effective size can still vary in multi-byte encodings because `n` denotes a maximum of characters, not bytes:

> strings up to `n` characters (not bytes) in length.

All of them use `varlena` internally.
`"char"` (with double-quotes) is a different creature and always occupies a single byte.
[Untyped string literals](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) (`'foo'`) have a single byte overhead. Not to be confused with typed values!

Test with [`pg_column_size()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE).

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (id int, v_small varchar, v_big varchar);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1, 'foo', '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890');

SELECT pg_column_size(id)        AS id
     , pg_column_size(v_small)   AS v_small
     , pg_column_size(v_big)     AS v_big
     , pg_column_size(t)         AS t
FROM   t
UNION ALL  -- 2nd row measuring values in RAM
SELECT pg_column_size(1)
     , pg_column_size('foo'::varchar)
     , pg_column_size('12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'::varchar)
     , pg_column_size(ROW(1, 'foo'::varchar, '12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890'::varchar));

 id | v_small | v_big |  t
----+---------+-------+-----
  4 |       4 |   144 | 176
  4 |       7 |   144 | 176
```

As you can see:

- The 3-byte string 'foo' occupies **4 bytes** on disk and **7 bytes** in RAM (so 1 byte vs. 4 bytes of overhead).
- The 140-byte string '123...' occupies 144 bytes both on disk and in RAM (so always 4 bytes of overhead).
- Storage of `integer` has no overhead (but it has alignment requirements that can impose padding).
- The row has an additional overhead of 24 bytes for the tuple header (plus an additional 4 bytes per tuple for the item identifier in the page header).
- And last but not least: The overhead of the small `varchar` is still just 1 byte while it has not been extracted from the row - as can be seen from the row size. (That's why it's sometimes a bit faster to select whole rows.)

Related:

- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)
- [Detailed optimal column order with large text and bytea](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/69800/detailed-optimal-column-order-with-large-text-and-bytea/69807#69807)
- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)