# Nested Loop with Materialize resulting in very slow query on postgresql 9.5

Tags: postgresql, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

I have an analytics database on Postgres 9.5
I'm taking advantage of constraint [partitioning](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/ddl-partitioning.html) with table inheritance to split up events into monthly tables. The base (parent) table contains no rows.

I have a relatively simple query but the planner is coming up with a completely insane plan where it materializes within a nested loop as can be seen from the explain.

The query

```
select count(person_id) as thecount from (
    select distinct A.person_id from event_page as O 
    join alias as A on (O.person_alias = A.alias) 
    where O.timestamp_ between '2017-4-28 04:00:00' and '2017-4-29 03:59:59.999' 
    and O.location_host = 'www.foo.com' AND O.location_path= '/ca/sale' 
) as alias_3494697
```

The explain: https://explain.depesz.com/s/IoO

My theory is that table inheritance with constraint partitioning is tripping up the planner somehow. If I replace the base table with the monthly table for April I get a sane plan with good performance:

https://explain.depesz.com/s/GpbU

NOTE The slight difference from the above query - i'm using the child table instead of the base table (ie no inheritance at play)

```
select count(person_id) as thecount from (
    select distinct A.person_id from event_page_2017_4 as O 
    join alias as A on (O.person_alias = A.alias) 
    where O.timestamp_ between '2017-4-28 04:00:00' and '2017-4-29 03:59:59.999' 
    and O.location_host = 'www.foo.com' AND O.location_path= '/ca/sale' 
) as alias_3494697
```

All stats are up to date via vacuum analyze. The relevant schema is below:

```
CREATE TABLE event_page (
    id                      CHAR(24) PRIMARY KEY,
    timestamp_              TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    person_alias            VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    visitor_id              VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    session_id              VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
    ip_address              VARCHAR(64) ,
    user_agent              VARCHAR(256) ,
    operating_system        VARCHAR(64) ,
    device_type             VARCHAR(64) ,
    browser                 VARCHAR(64) ,
    browser_major           VARCHAR(64) ,
    page_title              VARCHAR(1024) ,
    location_host           VARCHAR(256) ,
    location_path           VARCHAR(1024) ,
    location_query          VARCHAR(1024) ,
    location_fragment       VARCHAR(1024) ,
    referrer_host           VARCHAR(256) ,
    referrer_path           VARCHAR(1024) ,
    referrer_query          VARCHAR(1024) ,
    referrer_fragment       VARCHAR(1024) ,
        duration                INT
);



--the monthly tables all look like this example for April 2017
CREATE TABLE event_page_2017_4
(LIKE event_page including defaults including constraints including indexes,
CONSTRAINT page_2017_4_part CHECK ( timestamp_ >= '2017-4-01'::timestamp AND timestamp_ < '2017-05-01'::timestamp )
)
INHERITS (event_page);


--indexes are the sames on each of the monthly tables
CREATE INDEX ep_2017_4_location
  ON event_page_2017_4
  USING btree
  (location_host varchar_pattern_ops, location_path varchar_pattern_ops, location_query varchar_pattern_ops, location_fragment varchar_pattern_ops, timestamp_, person_alias, session_id);

CREATE INDEX ep_2017_4_ts
  ON event_page_2017_4
  USING btree
  (timestamp_, person_alias, session_id);

CREATE INDEX ep_2017_4_a_ses_ts 
  ON event_page_2017_4
  USING btree
  (person_alias, session_id, timestamp_); 


--the alias tables and two indexes
CREATE TABLE alias (
    person_id               CHAR(24),
    alias                   VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,
    first_seen              TIMESTAMP,
    soft                    BOOLEAN
);

ALTER TABLE ALIAS ADD CONSTRAINT alias_alias_pkey PRIMARY KEY(alias);
CREATE INDEX alias_a_p ON alias (alias, person_id);
CREATE INDEX alias_p_a ON alias (person_id, alias);
```

**NOTE:** The problem went away after upgrading to 9.6.1

Answer (score 4):

A couple of observations:

#### 1.

The query plan for the slow query shows:

> Seq Scan on event_page o (cost=**10,000,000,000.00**..10,000,000,000.00 rows=1 width=274)

... which indicates that you ran with `SET enable_seqscan = off;`. And that means your Postgres version positively could not find any other way than the sequential scan.

#### 2.

Did you enable [constraint_exclusion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION) like [the manual advises here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-IMPLEMENTATION):

> 6. Ensure that the [constraint_exclusion](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-CONSTRAINT-EXCLUSION) configuration parameter is not disabled in `postgresql.conf`. If it is, queries will not be optimized
>      as desired.

#### 3.

The day boundaries in your query are not in sync with the partitioning. (But that has no immediate effect for the given query, see comments.)
The `CHECK` constraint reads:

```
CHECK ( timestamp_ >= '2017-4-01'::timestamp AND timestamp_ < '2017-05-01'::timestamp )
```

There may be confusion with `timestamp` vs. `timestamptz` and / or time zones. Or something got lost in translation and the question is misleading in that respect.

Either way, the expression in your `WHERE` clause opens up a sneaky corner case (even if your day boundaries were in sync):

```
where O.timestamp_ between '2017-4-28 04:00:00' and '2017-4-29 03:59:59.999'
```

Postgres timestamps are implemented as 8-byte integers allowing 6 decimal places. A row with `'2017-4-29 03:59:59.9995'` would not behave as expected. 
Details:

- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

Plus, this does not play well with constraint exclusion. More partitions than necessary may have to be read.

Use instead:

```
WHERE o.timestamp_ >= '2017-4-28 04:00' -- include lower bound
AND   o.timestamp_ <  '2017-4-29 04:00' -- exclude upper bound
```

You may want get "days" in your partitions in sync with your queries - *00:00* vs. *04:00* (or the evil *03:59:59.999*) - and maybe use `timestamptz` to begin with.

#### 4.

I see for the index-only scan on `alias`:

> Heap Fetches: 1918543

... which is exceptionally high. There may or may not be problems with the [visibility map](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/storage-vm.html). (See also: [Updating The Visibility Map](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-VISIBILITY-MAP)) Did you run `VACUUM FULL` on the table(s)? (Compare [this thread on plpgsql-performance](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/flat/m3mwy0myn5.fsf%40mnc.ch#m3mwy0myn5.fsf@mnc.ch).) Try plain `VACUUM`, which updates the visibility map properly. But that's all hard to say, since you seem to have been running with `enable_seqscan = off`. Not sure how this plays out in combination with all the other stuff at work here.

There have been various improvements to `VACUUM` for Postgres 9.6 (among other things), this may explain the difference - or what you observed in pg 9.6 is coincidence and due to other factors.

#### 5.

If `alias.alias` is ***unique*** (and referential integrity can be assumed), the query can be simplified. Just `count(DISTINCT o.person_alias)` without even joining to table `alias` at all. Like:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT o.person_alias) AS thecount
FROM   event_page o
WHERE  o.timestamp_ >= '2017-4-28 04:00' -- include lower bound
AND    o.timestamp_ <  '2017-4-29 04:00' -- exclude upper bound
AND    o.location_host = 'www.foo.com'
AND    o.location_path = '/ca/sale';
```

(Or use the subquery like you had it, may be faster than `count(DISTINCT ...)`.)

If `alias.alias` is not unique, your query may be wrong / ambiguous.

Why do you have `person_alias` in table `event_page` and not `person_id` to begin with?

#### 6.

You use the data type `CHAR(24)` as PK for your tables, which is almost certainly a bad choice. Consider a `serial` or `bigserial` column or maybe a `uuid`. Numeric types are smaller and faster and not burdened by collation rules, varying byte length, etc. Related:

- [Would index lookup be noticeably faster with char vs varchar when all values are 36 chars](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/89429/would-index-lookup-be-noticeably-faster-with-char-vs-varchar-when-all-values-are/89433#89433)
- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/what-is-the-overhead-for-varcharn/125526#125526)

Comment: In my first draft I misread and assumed you had daily partitions. Since you have 1 partition per month, the comparison is fair after all. I leave the rest discussing partition bounds, since that's still relevant.

Comment: Thanks Erwin, to address your points:
1. Yes, enable_seqscan = off however the parent table is always empty, only the tables that inherit contain data.
2. Yes, constrain exclusion is set to `partition`, the default
3. You lost me here. The monthly partitions are set up to with inclusive & exclusive bounds and there should be no overlap. Isn't '2017-4-01' equivalent to '2017-4-01 00:00:00.000'? Based on my experiments the constraint partitions worked as expected.
4. VACUUM FULL (rewrite) did lower the heap fetches

Comment: continued....
5. A person may have one or more aliases hence the join. A person's alias may change throughout their life. I'm interested in finding the distinct people which is always <= to the distinct aliases. 
6. Will look into this, thanks for the tip

Comment: @maxTrialfire: 3. See my comment and updates, I had misread the date format. 4. `VACUUM` is superior to `VACUUM FULL` for updating the visibility map. 5. Makes sense now. (Did you ensure that aliases are unambiguous over time?)

Comment: Edited the question to include PK constraint on `alias` which I seem to have left out.