# Decrease size of database (with an expression index)?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, index, performance, disk-space, postgresql-performance

This is my current table definition in a Postgres 10.1-1 database:

```
CREATE TYPE CUSTOMER_TYPE AS ENUM
('enum1', 'enum2', 'enum3', '...', 'enum15');     -- max length of enum names ~15

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(
   CUSTOMER_ONE    TEXT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,     -- max 35 char String
   ATTRIBUTE_ONE   TEXT UNIQUE,                   -- max 35 char String
   ATTRIBUTE_TWO   TEXT,                          -- 1-80 char String
   PRIVATEKEYTYPE  CUSTOMER_TYPE                  -- see enum
);
```

It results in about 4.3x more database size compared to the size of the inserted data. (50 MB, 700.000 lines --> database size is 210 MB)

`Attribute_One` is computed as `hash(Customer_One)`.

**Requirements:** fast searches (using algorithms) for columns `CUSTOMER_ONE` and `ATTRIBUTE_ONE`. (That's why I think I need an index.)

Typical search query:

```
select * from customer
where Customer_One='XXX' OR Attribute_One='XXX';
```

Each `SELECT` can find a maximum of 1 or 0 matching rows in millions of rows.

Is it possible to further decrease the DB size? I have been told to use an expression index but don't fully understand how this works. A short explanation with an example index or other solution would be great

Is the ***insert speed*** effected by those indexes? The faster the better. (To be clear: search speed is more important than insert speed.)

Comment: You omitted important details. In a [comment to your your previous question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193126/why-is-my-database-12-times-bigger-than-inserted-data#comment375856_193135) you mentioned: `Attribute_One is calculated from Customer_One`. How exactly? And what "algorithms" do you use in your "fast searches"? Show a typical example query. Also: your version of Postgres, please.

Comment: Attribute_One = Hash(Customer_One); I dont use any specific search algorithms, I want Postgres to use them (and be able to do it). Each select can find a maximum of 1 or 0 matching rows in millions of rows. PG version v.10.1-1. Typical search: select * from customer where Customer_One='XXX' OR Attribute_One='XXX'. Thank you :)

Comment: All defining information should go into your *question*, not comments.

Comment: Done! Sorry, wasnt aware of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `hash()` is an `IMMUTABLE` function (which should be the case for a function called "hash"!) you can omit storing the functionally dependent `attribute_one` in the table altogether and add an [**expression index**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-expressional.html) to support queries on the expression `hash(customer_one)`:

```
CREATE TABLE customer (
   privatekeytype customer_type     -- move the enum to 1st pos to save some more 
 , customer_one   text PRIMARY KEY
 , attribute_two  text
);
```

Expression index:

```
CREATE INDEX customer_attribute_one_idx ON customer (hash(customer_one));
```

This is exactly as big (identical) as the index supporting your original `UNIQUE` constraint on the redundant column `attribute_one`.

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   customer 
WHERE  'XXX' IN (customer_one, hash(customer_one));
```

Testing with `EXPLAIN` you'll see index or bitmap index scans like:

> ```
> ->  BitmapOr  (cost=5.34..5.34 rows=5 width=0)
>      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on customer_pkey  (cost=0.00..2.66 rows=1 width=0)
>            Index Cond: ('XXX'::text = customer.customer_one)
>      ->  Bitmap Index Scan on customer_attribute_one_idx  (cost=0.00..2.68 rows=4 width=0)
>            Index Cond: ('XXX'::text = hash(customer.customer_one))
> ```

About the same performance as with the redundant table column or faster since the table is smaller, yet - which helps overall performance in various ways.

Moving the `enum` to first position saves a few bytes of alignment padding per row as explained in my previous answer:

- [Why is my database 12 times bigger than inserted data?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/193126/why-is-my-database-12-times-bigger-than-inserted-data/193135#193135)

Why does the function have to be `IMMUTABLE`? See:

- [How do IMMUTABLE, STABLE and VOLATILE keywords effect behaviour of function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28569415/how-do-immutable-stable-and-volatile-keywords-effect-behaviour-of-function/28573737#28573737)
- [Does PostgreSQL support “accent insensitive” collations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11005036/does-postgresql-support-accent-insensitive-collations/11007216#11007216)