# How to determine or predict space on disk per table row?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, disk-space, database-size

I'm very new to Postgres so my math could be off here ...

This is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE audit (
    id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    content_id VARCHAR (50) NULL, 
    type VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL, 
    size bigint NOT NULL, 
    timestamp1 timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW(), 
    timestamp2 timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT NOW()
);
```

I want to make some estimations on how much space 1 row would occupy. After some reading I've come up with this, is it correct?

```
1 row =
23 (heaptupleheader)
+ 1 (padding)
+ 8 (id)
+ 50 (content_id)
+ 6 (padding)
+ 100 (type)
+ 4 (padding)
+ 8 (size)
+ 8 (timestamp)
+ 8 (timestamp)
= 216 bytes
```

I also created this same table in my local Postgres DB but the numbers don't seem to match:

```
INSERT INTO public.audit(content_id, type, size)
    VALUES ('aaa', 'bbb', 100);

SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('audit') );  -- returns 24 kb

INSERT INTO public.audit(content_id, type, size)
    VALUES ('aaaaaaaaaaaaa', 'bbbbbbbbbbbbbb', 100000000000);

SELECT pg_size_pretty( pg_total_relation_size('audit') ); -- still returns 24 kb
```

Which brings me to think that Postgres reserves a space of 24 kb to start with and as I put in more data it will get incremented by 132 bytes once I go beyond 24 kb? But something inside me says that can't be right.

I want to see how much space 1 row would occupy in Postgres db so I can analyze how much data I can potentially store in it. Maybe I'm missing something very obvious.

Comment: Related to https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row, but clearly no duplicate. I question the judgement of the close votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your calculation is close for the maximum bare row size. The actual range is 68 - 212 bytes per row, or 84 - 228 bytes including the index.

Most importantly a `varchar(n)` does not have to occupy the maximum length. The data type is implemented with `varlena` internally, which adds 1 byte overhead for short strings on disk, plus the actual number of bytes for the string.

Data types implemented with `varlena` don't require alignment padding on disk.

And a NULL value (allowed for `content_id`) is effectively free. See:

- [Does not using NULL in PostgreSQL still use a NULL bitmap in the header?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7383198/939860)

Finally the `PRIMARY KEY` constraint is implemented using a standard btree index. We have to add that to the total size on disk.

So the calculation for the row size on disk is:

```
23        bytes  tuple header
 1        byte   padding or null bitmap
 8        bytes  id BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY
 0 - 51   bytes  content_id VARCHAR (50) NULL
 0        bytes  alignement padding
 2 - 101  bytes  type VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
 ?        bytes  alignment padding
 8        bytes  size bigint NOT NULL
 8        bytes  timestamp1 timestamp NOT NULL 
 8        bytes  timestamp2 timestamp NOT NULL
---
min 64 (incl 6 bytes padding) - max 208 bytes (no padding required)

+ 4      bytes item identifier in heap page
---
68 - 212 bytes

+ 16     bytes for the index tuple
---
84 - 228 bytes
```

Plus some overhead for heap pages and index pages as detailed in these related questions:

- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)
- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Actual row sizes on disk (without item identifier):

```
SELECT pg_column_size(a) AS size_on_disk, *
FROM   audit a;
```

Note that size in RAM can differ:

```
SELECT pg_column_size(content_id) AS content_id_size_on_disk
     , pg_column_size(content_id || '') AS content_id_size_in_ram
     , content_id
FROM   audit a;
```

See:

- [What is the overhead for varchar(n)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/125499/what-is-the-overhead-for-varcharn/125526#125526)

---

About ...

> Which brings me to think that Postgres reserves a space of 24 kb to start

The heap starts with 0 bytes. The index starts with one meta-page (8kb).
After adding the first row, we see a minimum of 8 kb for the first heap page and 16 kb for the index (1 meta page + 1st index page). Details in the fiddle!

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=de9645e58bc36e9673c4ae46e9cbe55c)*

Comment: thanks a lot sir! this is very eloquently written. gives me a lot to think.

Answer (score 0):

The [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADMIN-DBSIZE) and the following [StackOverflow question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41991380/whats-the-difference-between-pg-table-size-pg-relation-size-pg-total-relatio) provide a good starting point.

Comment: While the links may contain content that answers the question, links can change over time and the content can be entirely removed. This will invalidate your answer in the future. Please expand your answer to include the relevant information from those links such that you directly answer the question. That way, if the links change, your answer will remain valid.