# PostgreSQL: smallint vs "char"

Tags: postgresql, disk-space

```
 CREATE TABLE test_size1 AS SELECT (random() * 1e3)::int id, (random() * 10)::smallint col1, (random() * 10)::smallint col2 FROM generate_series(1, 1e6);

 attname | typname | typalign | typlen
---------+---------+----------+--------
 id      | int4    | i        |      4
 col1    | int2    | s        |      2
 col2    | int2    | s        |      2

              metric               |  bytes   | bytes_pretty | bytes_per_row
-----------------------------------+----------+--------------+---------------
 core_relation_size                | 36249600 | 35 MB        |            36
 visibility_map                    |     8192 | 8192 bytes   |             0
 free_space_map                    |    32768 | 32 kB        |             0
 table_size_incl_toast             | 36290560 | 35 MB        |            36
 indexes_size                      |        0 | 0 bytes      |             0
 total_size_incl_toast_and_indexes | 36290560 | 35 MB        |            36
 live_rows_in_text_representation  |  8991442 | 8781 kB      |             8
 ------------------------------    |          |              |
 row_count                         |  1000000 |              |
 live_tuples                       |  1000000 |              |
 dead_tuples                       |        0 |              |

CREATE TABLE test_size3 (id int, col1 "char", col2 "char");
insert into test_size3 SELECT (random() * 1e3)::int id, chr((random() * 10)::smallint + 1) col1, chr((random() * 10)::smallint + 1) col2 FROM generate_series(1, 1e6);

 attname | typname | typalign | typlen
---------+---------+----------+--------
 id      | int4    | i        |      4
 col1    | char    | c        |      1
 col2    | char    | c        |      1

              metric               |  bytes   | bytes_pretty | bytes_per_row
-----------------------------------+----------+--------------+---------------
 core_relation_size                | 36249600 | 35 MB        |            36
 visibility_map                    |     8192 | 8192 bytes   |             0
 free_space_map                    |    32768 | 32 kB        |             0
 table_size_incl_toast             | 36290560 | 35 MB        |            36
 indexes_size                      |        0 | 0 bytes      |             0
 total_size_incl_toast_and_indexes | 36290560 | 35 MB        |            36
 live_rows_in_text_representation  |  9894817 | 9663 kB      |             9
 ------------------------------    |          |              |
 row_count                         |  1000000 |              |
 live_tuples                       |  1000000 |              |
 dead_tuples                       |        0 |              |
```

I expected test_size1 and test_size3 tables would have different sizes (test_size2 should be smaller by 2 bytes per row). However it's not the case, they have identical sizes, even though smallint is supposed to occupy 2 bytes while "char" is only 1 byte. It looks like I'm missing something, please share if you know the root cause of this behaviour (I've checked pg13 and pg14).

(**upd #1**)
I've created new tables test_size11 and test_size33, just to make sure nothing weird is happening because columns in previous tables were nullable. Sizes remained exactly the same - I'll omit the details.

```
             Table "public.test_size11"
 Column |   Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+----------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer  |           | not null |
 col1   | smallint |           | not null |
 col2   | smallint |           | not null |

            Table "public.test_size33"
 Column |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id     | integer |           | not null |
 col1   | "char"  |           | not null |
 col2   | "char"  |           | not null |
```

Alignment padding shouldn't be the issue, given the order and type of columns.

Comment: Alignment and padding, see e.g. here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/267424

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine or predict space on disk per table row?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267413/how-to-determine-or-predict-space-on-disk-per-table-row)

Comment: If this link have explanation for this - I don't see it. As far as I understand, there should be 0 alignment padding in both tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forget that the tuple itself must me maxaligned, so there could be padding *between* the tuples that swallows the space you are saving.