# Query performance on static, large PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, database-design, query-performance, postgresql-performance, read-only-database

I tried to have this as detailed as possible. Sorry about the length!

#### Background

I created the following partitioned table `protein_snp_assoc` on a PostgreSQL (version 12.13) database:

```
CREATE TABLE protein_snp_assoc (
  protein_id    int not null,
  snp_id        int not null,
  beta          double precision,
  se            double precision,
  logp          double precision
) PARTITION BY RANGE (snp_id);
```

I then created 51 partitions, each containing roughly 150 million lines (total lines 7.65 billion), based on the following template:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS protein_snp_assoc_(x) PARTITION OF protein_snp_assoc
  FOR VALUES FROM (y) TO (z);
```

where `x` ranged from 1 to 51, and `y, z` defined intervals, each of length 150,000. As an example, the first two and last partitions are:

```
protein_snp_assoc_1 FOR VALUES FROM (1) TO (150001),
protein_snp_assoc_2 FOR VALUES FROM (150001) TO (300001), ...
protein_snp_assoc_51 FOR VALUES FROM (7500001) TO (7650001)
```

The variable column `protein_id` has 1,000 unique values (1 to 1,000) and `snp_id` has 7,500,000 unique values (1 to 7,650,001). As the pair `(snp_id, protein_id)` uniquely determines a row in the table, I used the two columns to create a BTree index, with `snp_id` as the left-most variable:

```
CREATE INDEX ON protein_snp_assoc (snp_id, protein_id);
```

This will be a static database. It currently has about 20% of the total data that will be on it (since I'm prototyping), but once all the data has been added to the database, no further rows will be added (nor deleted).

#### Typical queries

The most common queries will be (a) single SNP/protein queries, (b) single protein, multiple SNPs queries, and (c) multiple proteins and multiple SNPs queries.

Example queries where I use `VALUES` as I read on this site that it can increase performance when `IN(...)` has multiple values.

```
-- Single SNP/protein
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  protein_snp_assoc
WHERE
  snp_id IN (VALUES (1))
AND
  protein_id IN (VALUES(1));
  
-- Multiple SNPs, single protein
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  protein_snp_assoc
WHERE
  snp_id IN (VALUES (1), (2))
AND
  protein_id IN (VALUES(1));
  
-- Multiple SNPs, multiple proteins
SELECT 
  * 
FROM 
  protein_snp_assoc 
WHERE
  snp_id IN (VALUES (1), (2))
AND
  protein_id IN (VALUES (1),(2));
```

The `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` for each query can be seen here (pastebin links):

[Single SNP/protein (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/zfaRCibT), [Multiple SNPs, single protein (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/jLdu2hqJ), [Mulitple SNPs, mulitple protein (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/MYjBxjpT).

#### Benchmarking and comparison to Arrow/parquet

I ran 1,000 queries for multiple SNP/protein combinations, where the SNPs and proteins were randomly drawn before being inserted into the query. To get some sort of reference, I converted the raw data files I used to populate the database to `.parquet` files and ran similar queries using R and the `arrow` package. The results can be seen in the table below (all times are in milliseconds, `lq` and `uq` are the 25% and 75% percentiles, respectively).

| index | n_snps | n_proteins | min | lq | mean | median | uq | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| postgres | 1 | 1 | 0.05900 | 14.71125 | 18.02112 | 17.92850 | 21.14350 | 45.2850 |
| arrow | 1 | 1 | 34.31822 | 44.62842 | 49.30316 | 46.29033 | 48.07222 | 577.1411 |
| postgres | 1 | 2 | 4.07100 | 20.97125 | 25.40618 | 25.15250 | 29.35375 | 68.7700 |
| arrow | 1 | 2 | 47.61873 | 61.47562 | 67.87060 | 63.99824 | 65.68011 | 629.5121 |
| postgres | 10 | 1 | 118.18900 | 167.11100 | 181.76304 | 180.50250 | 196.41475 | 262.9640 |
| arrow | 10 | 1 | 138.73902 | 164.25678 | 177.47847 | 167.69684 | 176.15489 | 704.3115 |
| postgres | 10 | 2 | 168.10500 | 231.74825 | 248.74577 | 248.45400 | 264.95825 | 330.2810 |
| arrow | 10 | 2 | 219.73495 | 269.54206 | 287.34815 | 281.79291 | 286.22803 | 819.4827 |
| postgres | 10 | 10 | 731.77300 | 893.28625 | 940.90282 | 941.69650 | 989.38625 | 1162.4810 |
| arrow | 10 | 10 | 930.18264 | 1038.39510 | 1089.43522 | 1080.01131 | 1100.22580 | 2313.4975 |
| postgres | 50 | 1 | 665.23800 | 799.89600 | 849.73860 | 850.91900 | 898.27900 | 1050.0710 |
| arrow | 50 | 1 | 682.10049 | 711.62065 | 766.24498 | 735.49283 | 750.97367 | 1335.6018 |

As you can see, as the number of SNPs or proteins (or both) were increased, PostgreSQL and Arrow started performing similarly (although the worst-case for Arrow was consistently worse).

#### Hardware

[CPU (pastebin)](https://pastebin.com/Xr2Y7NLh). The HDD is a Seagate IronWolf 10TB (ST10000VN0008). Memory is 64GB but I can't see the specific type since I don't have `sudo` privileges on the machine. Operating system: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS.

#### My question

The results of the benchmark make me believe that my database is not optimized. I'm worried that as I start adding more data to the database, performance will suffer. Is there any way I can speed up queries that involve multiple proteins and SNPs, either with better design, queries or some other sort of tuning?

#### Update 2023-03-12

Thanks to Erwin and everyone else who has engaged. I followed Erwin's directions exactly (the only exception being that I couldn't update from v12 to v15) and then redid the benchmarks for this new table. Here are the results (compared to the original design), where `index_order = snp_first` is the original design and `index_order = protein_first` is the design proposed by Erwin:

| index_order | n_snps | n_proteins | min | lq | mean | median | uq | max |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| snp_first | 1 | 1 | 0.059 | 14.71125 | 18.02112 | 17.9285 | 21.14350 | 45.285 |
| protein_first | 1 | 1 | 0.060 | 20.96200 | 24.87686 | 26.3945 | 30.31275 | 126.046 |
| snp_first | 1 | 2 | 4.071 | 20.97125 | 25.40618 | 25.1525 | 29.35375 | 68.770 |
| protein_first | 1 | 2 | 2.764 | 37.02300 | 44.31820 | 45.7595 | 52.30925 | 84.515 |
| snp_first | 10 | 1 | 118.189 | 167.11100 | 181.76304 | 180.5025 | 196.41475 | 262.964 |
| protein_first | 10 | 1 | 29.754 | 215.37700 | 221.30159 | 255.3445 | 276.62725 | 380.930 |
| snp_first | 10 | 2 | 168.105 | 231.74825 | 248.74577 | 248.4540 | 264.95825 | 330.281 |
| protein_first | 10 | 2 | 88.473 | 320.08475 | 417.07273 | 461.6155 | 501.66350 | 593.604 |
| snp_first | 10 | 10 | 731.773 | 893.28625 | 940.90282 | 941.6965 | 989.38625 | 1162.481 |
| protein_first | 10 | 10 | 1189.058 | 1906.78050 | 2040.40170 | 2054.9985 | 2194.80550 | 2595.215 |
| snp_first | 50 | 1 | 665.238 | 799.89600 | 849.73860 | 850.9190 | 898.27900 | 1050.071 |
| protein_first | 50 | 1 | 200.521 | 910.52700 | 934.64351 | 1091.5340 | 1149.79875 | 1319.777 |

As you can see, the original design is considerably faster, especially on the most time-consuming queries. I'll have a chat with the sys admin about updating to v15 this week, to see if that improves performance. In any case, I think this experiment has demonstrated that this is either a query problem (the queries I wrote are probably suboptimal, see comments on how I use `VALUES`) or a hardware problem (the server is old).

**Answers to some questions in comments**

*jjanes:* See this pastebin: https://pastebin.com/qQR3GtZ4

*a_horse_with_no_name*: The `VALUES` idea came from here: [Optimizing a Postgres query with a large IN](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91247/optimizing-a-postgres-query-with-a-large-in)

I wrote a test query:

```
EXPLAIN
WITH value_list (protein_id, snp_id) as (
  values
    (1, 1),
    (1, 2)
)
SELECT 
  *
FROM protein_snp_assoc AS p
INNER JOIN
value_list v on (p.protein_id, snp_id) = (v.protein_id, v.snp_id);
```

I thought this gave me the same query plan as `WHERE/IN` but I see now I was wrong. I'll look into this and see if it's better. **Edit:** it seems to perform on par with `WHERE/IN` and `VALUES`. So I guess this isn't the real bottleneck.

*bobflux*: I can't share the data but you can simulate it easily. Here's a quick example in R:

```
sim_data <- function(i, n_snps) {
  data.frame(
    protein_id = rep(i, n_snps),
    snp_id = 1:n_snps,
    beta = rnorm(n = n_snps, mean = 0, sd = 1),
    se = abs(rnorm(n = n_snps, mean = 0, sd = 1)),
    logp = abs(rnorm(n = n_snps, mean = 2, sd = 1))
  )
}
protein_id <- 10
n_snps <- 7650000
sim_data(protein_id, n_snps)
```

*nz_21*: I wrote custom scripts in R and bash.

Comment: Well written question, though I'm not sure the arrow stuff is particularly necessary. Partitioning isn't designed to improve performance AFAIK. How did you time your tests? The database execution time reported in the explain plans seems lower than the mean values reported. Seems like the execution time increases roughly linearly with the number of results retrieved which doesn't feel unreasonable?

Comment: I ran `EXPLAIN (FORMAT JSON, ANALYZE) ...` and pulled the execution time from the resulting JSON. The pastebin queries might be faster due to caching. Edit: I forgot to mention, I have the arrow comparison here because I expected Postgres to perform better? Maybe that's a poor assumption.

Comment: I am curious: why write ` snp_id IN (VALUES (1), (2))` rather than `snp_id in (1,2)` (not that it would matter for performance though)

Comment: If the data isn't "top secret", could you share a slice of it, perhaps a gigabyte? I'd like to try something with Clickhouse. I will need all 5 columns (including the three floats) because that will be important for data compression.

Comment: Great question. How did you run all the benchmarks? Did you invoke a custom script? Did you some framework?

Comment: The idea of using a VALUES is that are supposed to JOIN to the VALUES pseudo-table instead of using an IN.  Just sticking the VALUES inside an IN is unlikely to accomplish anything.

Comment: Your plans aren't very useful, as they are not run with the queries that are actually challenging.  do `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` on a query with 10 randomly chosen value of both fields (not the same 10 that were just recently used).  Preferably turn track_io_timing on first (but that requires privileged access.)

Comment: I tried answering all of the questions I got here in my original post. See section **Answers to some questions in comments**. If it's not kosher to answer questions this way, I'm sorry.

Comment: Are you sure you are testing what you actually need to test? You tested `1,000 queries ... SNPs and proteins ... randomly drawn`. Is that the expected workload? Each next query has completely random filters without correlation to the last. This is crucially important. With your slow disk and not enough RAM to cache everything, **very** slow disk reads will dominate query times. Typically, you would have some kind of clustering, multiple consecutive queries revolving around similar values. Then the cache can kick in, and queries are faster by orders of magnitude.

Comment: Also, you tested with `20% of the total data`. That's still in the realm where your 64 GB of RAM (or what's left of it) can cache the index (but not index and table). With a 100 % your RAM is severely outmatched by table and index size. Performance will get **a lot** worse. (And my proposed design will help some more.) "min" times are 1.5 - 4 x faster with my index, except for the query with 10x10, which is probably dominated by disk reads most of the time. Those min times (or faster) should be your "typical" times as soon as the slow disk is out of the picture due to caching ...

Comment: Sorry I should have been more specific. The data for 1,000 proteins IS 20% of the data. I have up to 5,000 proteins or about 35 billion rows. And yes, I don't know which protein/snp combinations will be of interest at any time so querying has to be random.

Comment: @jommi. Then disk reads will always dominate query times (unless you seriously mess up queries), and the most important ingredient (by far) will be to a) minimize disk footprint like I demonstrated; b) cluster table data and index as much as possible matching typical access patterns, like I demonstrated; and  c) (most importantly) get a much faster "disk", meaning SSD instead of HDD. **And** as much RAM as you can get.

Comment: And yes, you should really test with Postgres 15, not Postgres 12.

Comment: Alright. Thank you very much Erwin. I'll accept your answer!

Comment: Note a couple more improvements I added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on this:

> - `protein_id` has 1,000 unique values
> - `snp_id` has 7,500,000 unique values
> - the pair `(snp_id, protein_id)` uniquely determines a row in the table
>
> Typical queries:
> (a) single SNP/protein queries
> (b) single protein, multiple SNPs queries
> (c) multiple proteins and multiple SNPs queries
>
> Table is read-only.

I don't see the benefit of partitioning. **Drop partitioning** and use a plain table instead:

```
CREATE TABLE protein_snp_assoc (
  protein_id int
, snp_id     int
, beta       double precision
, se         double precision
, logp       double precision
);
```

*After* filling the table, add this PK:

```
ALTER TABLE protein_snp_assoc
ADD CONSTRAINT protein_snp_assoc_pkey
    PRIMARY KEY (protein_id, snp_id) WITH (FILLFACTOR = 100);
```

Notably, the PK replaces your index `protein_snp_assoc`, but with **leading `protein_id`**, since that is more commonly the single value in your queries. With **`FILLFACTOR = 100`** since your table is read-only. Default for B-tree indexes is 90. See:

- [Fillfactor for a sequential index that is PK](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14187367/939860)

Apart from the 10 % savings, size of the underlying index is the same. Two `integer` columns is pretty ideal for your multicolumn index. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Once populated, [**cluster the table**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-cluster.html) *once* on the PK:

```
CLUSTER TABLE protein_snp_assoc USING protein_snp_assoc_pkey;
```

Expensive for the huge table, but do it once. This rewrites table and index, so that you have both in pristine condition.

**Or** (better) if at all possible, fill the table with sorted data to begin with. Ideally use **`COPY` with `FREEZE`**:

```
COPY protein_snp_assoc FROM '/path/to/filename' WITH (FREEZE);
```

.. after creating or truncating the table in the same transaction. Read about [`FREEZE` in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html). And [this](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/populate.html#POPULATE-COPY-FROM):

> `COPY` is fastest when used within the same transaction as an earlier
> `CREATE TABLE` or `TRUNCATE` command. In such cases no WAL needs to be
> written, because in case of an error, the files containing the newly
> loaded data will be removed anyway. However, this consideration only
> applies when [`wal_level`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-wal.html#GUC-WAL-LEVEL) is `minimal` as all commands must write
> WAL otherwise.

You must be superuser, and have access to the server filesystem, which should be the case. Else, the next-best option is [`\copy`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) instead of `COPY`.

Either way, add the PK only *after* filling the table. That's a lot cheaper, and you get an index in pristine condition right away. Read the manual about [populating a database](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/populate.html).

Turn off [`autovacuum`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/routine-vacuuming.html) for this read-only table right from the start. And run a single `VACUUM ANALYZE protein_snp_assoc` after populating it. (Or `VACUUM FREEZE ANALYZE protein_snp_assoc` if you didn't go the `COPY ... FREEZE` route.) With your even data distribution, column statistics are not very critical, but you still need them, and the updated visibility map.

Either way, and crucially, rows with the same leading `protein_id` are now physically clustered, which minimizes the number of data pages that have to be read to satisfy your queries.

The table will have around 420 GB in pristine condition and the index a little over 140 GB. 7.5 billion rows x 20 bytes per index tuple (plus some overhead) or 60 bytes per table row. See:

- [How to determine or predict space on disk per table row?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267413/how-to-determine-or-predict-space-on-disk-per-table-row/267424#267424)
- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

After we have now minimized and optimized the disk footprint, **caching** the index will be crucial, especially with your 3.5" rotating disk. 64 GB of RAM is not exactly overkill. Postgres (in cooperation with the underlying OS) will still cache the most frequently accessed parts of index and table, and if you happen to focus on a subset of `protein_id` at a time, then that will still cover most of what needs to be cached. If your queries are all over the place all the time, 256 GB or more would help (a lot).

**Update:** You revealed in comments that there are 5 times as many rows. And read patterns are completely random. So you are back to disk-reads dominating the cost. You must get **faster storage**. SSD instead of HDD, there is no good alternative to that. Plus, all the RAM you can get to at least cache the most frequented parts of the index.

Do all of this with the **latest version of Postgres** ([Postgres 15.2 at the time of writing](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)) since there has been a steady flow of performance improvements, especially for big data.

Comment: Nice answer, +1 for sorting data before insertion

Comment: I think you should recommend `VACUUM (FREEZE)` rather than disabling autovacuum. Anti-wraparound autovacuum cannot be disabled.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I've updated my original post with the benchmark results on a table created per your specifications. It looks like design is not the problem but rather how I write the queries or hardware.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Yes, `FREEZE` is another improvement! Even better directly with `COPY ... (FREEZE)`. But in addition to disabling `autovacuum` for the table, not instead. (Even if anti-wraparound isn't turned off by that completely.)