# Why is my composite index on 3 int columns smaller than the PK index on 1 int column?

Tags: postgresql, index, database-size

I have a table called `data_table`. Below are schema, indexes, and their sizes.

```
                                        Table "public.data_table"
  Column   |           Type           | Collation | Nullable |                Default
-----------+--------------------------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------
 id        | integer                  |           | not null | nextval('data_table_id_seq'::regclass)
 col1_id   | integer                  |           | not null |
 col2_id   | integer                  |           | not null |
 col3_id   | integer                  |           | not null |
 col4      | double precision         |           | not null |
 timestamp | timestamp with time zone |           | not null |
Indexes:                                                     Size
    "data_table_1col_idx" btree (col1_id)                   8032 KB
    "data_table_2col_idx" btree (col2_id)                   8040 KB
    "data_table_3col_idx" btree (col3_id)                   8048 KB
    "data_table_4col_idx" btree (col4)                      25 MB
    "data_table_epe_idx" btree (col1_id, col2_id, col3_id)  8216 KB
    "data_table_pkey" btree (id)                            25 MB
```

`data_table` has a total of 1184330 rows.

```
select count(*) from "data_table";
  count
---------
 1184330
(1 row)

select * from "data_table" limit 5;
    id     | col1_id | col2_id | col3_id |   col4    |         timestamp
-----------+---------+--------+----------+-----------+----------------------------
 180102529 |       1 |      1 |        1 |  83.70361 | 2023-12-13 09:30:49.257+00
 180102530 |       1 |      1 |        2 |    2827.6 | 2023-12-13 09:30:49.257+00
 180102531 |       1 |      1 |        3 | 124.25156 | 2023-12-13 09:30:49.257+00
 180102532 |       1 |      1 |        4 |      43.3 | 2023-12-13 09:30:49.257+00
 180102533 |       1 |      1 |        5 |     282.4 | 2023-12-13 09:30:49.257+00
(5 rows)
```

`col1_id` is the primary key of table_1 and table_1 has the total number of rows is 11.

`col2_id` is the primary key of table_2 and table_2 has the total number of rows is 19.

`col3_id` is the primary key of table_3 and table_3 has the total number of rows is 115.

As you can see `data_table_epe_idx` is my composite index and has a size of around 8MB whereas `data_table_pkey` is the default index and has a size of 25MB.

**Why is the size of the composite index (3x integer) less than the size of the PK index (1x integer)?**

Comment: Are there lots of equal values in `col1_id`, `col2_id` and `col3_id`, so that the index can use deduplication (available from v13 on)?

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe, Yes there are lots of equal values in the "data_table".

Answer (score 4):

25 MB for the index `"data_table_pkey" btree (id)` is its **minimum possible size**. 1184330 rows, 8+8+4 = 20 bytes per index tuple, default fillfactor for B-tree index = 0.9 (plus negligible overheads per page & index). See:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

So:

```
1184330 * 20 * 1.11 = 25 MB
```

The index is in pristine condition, no bloat. Typically, B-tree indices exhibit at least some bloat. You must have cleaned up recently, or there have been barely any writes since the index was created.

Without [**index deduplication**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/btree-implementation.html#BTREE-DEDUPLICATION) (Postgres 13+), the other index on `(col1_id, col2_id, col3_id)` with a tuple size of 8+4+4+4+4+4 = 28 bytes per index tuple, would occupy at least 35 MB:

```
1184330 * 28 * 1.11 = 35 MB
```

With deduplication, each duplicate entry can be reduced to a ctid (6 bytes) in the "posting list". So the minimum possible size for your table is a bit above:

```
1184330 * 6 * 1.11 = 7703 kB
```

Your indices on `col1_id` - `col3_id` are all close to that:

```
"data_table_1col_idx" btree (col1_id)                   8032 KB
"data_table_2col_idx" btree (col2_id)                   8040 KB
"data_table_3col_idx" btree (col3_id)                   8048 KB
"data_table_epe_idx"  btree (col1_id, col2_id, col3_id) 8216 KB
```

So all of them consist of mostly dupes - no surprise with so few distinct values for `col1_id` - `col3_id` (11 -115).

My only call to action is this: **`DROP INDEX data_table_1col_idx;`** at your earliest convenience. The leading `col1_id` in `data_table_epe_idx` does the job probably even better. (Shared indices have a better chance to remain cached.) And with only 12 distinct values in `col1_id` an "included" column might be all you need.

An additional index on just `(col1_id)` only makes sense with a substantially smaller size (bigger index tuple, less deduplication) and/or substantially less index bloat (additional columns can cause more index bloat) and/or more distinct values.

It's probably beneficial to replace `"data_table_2col_idx" btree (col2_id)` with `"data_table_2col_3col_idx" btree (col2_id, col3_id)`. Arriving at:

```
"data_table_col123_idx" btree (col1_id, col2_id, col3_id)
"data_table_col23_idx"  btree (col2_id, col3_id
"data_table_3col_idx"   btree (col3_id)
```

Or, since the multicolumn index `data_table_epe_idx` is barely any bigger, and there seems to be hardly any index bloat (?), even:

```
"data_table_col123_idx" btree (col1_id, col2_id, col3_id)
"data_table_col231_idx" btree (col2_id, col3_id, col1_id)
"data_table_col312_idx" btree (col3_id, col1_id, col2_id)
```

See:

- [How to determine or predict space on disk per table row?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/267413/how-to-determine-or-predict-space-on-disk-per-table-row/267424#267424)
- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)