# Index for a Postgres query with a sort and an equality

Tags: postgresql, index, optimization, performance, postgresql-performance

This query is very slow:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, buffers) SELECT *
FROM
    "Follows" AS "Follow"
INNER JOIN "Users" AS "followee" ON "Follow"."followeeId" = "followee"."id"
WHERE
    "Follow"."followerId" = 169368
ORDER BY
    "Follow"."createdAt" DESC
LIMIT 1000;
```

Here is the explain:

```
Limit  (cost=0.86..2120.08 rows=141 width=814) (actual time=0.776..239.289 rows=262 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=750 read=673 dirtied=1
  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..2120.08 rows=141 width=814) (actual time=0.774..239.148 rows=262 loops=1)
        Buffers: shared hit=750 read=673 dirtied=1
        ->  Index Scan using follows_followinglist_followerid_createdat_idx on "Follows" "Follow"  (cost=0.43..681.88 rows=170 width=41) (actual time=0.377..52.687 rows=262 loops=1)
              Index Cond: ("followerId" = 169368)
              Buffers: shared hit=149 read=115
        ->  Index Scan using "Users_pkey" on "Users" followee  (cost=0.43..8.45 rows=1 width=773) (actual time=0.559..0.709 rows=1 loops=262)
              Index Cond: (id = "Follow"."followeeId")
              Buffers: shared hit=601 read=558 dirtied=1
Total runtime: 239.545 ms
```

I have the following indexes (currently, it is using the first one):

```
CREATE INDEX follows_followinglist_followerid_createdat_idx ON "Follows"
  ("followerId", "createdAt" DESC)
CREATE INDEX follows_followinglist_followerid_createdat_idx2 ON "Follows"
  ("createdAt" DESC, "followerId")
CREATE INDEX follows_followerId_fk_index ON "Follows" ("followerId");
CREATE INDEX  "follows_createdat_index" ON "public"."Follows" USING btree("createdAt" DESC);
```

Before I added the first two, the cost was slightly lower (~2000) using `follows_followerId_fk_index`, but still too slow.

I'm wondering if there's a way to optimize this further.

Comment: Do you need `SELECT *` for this query?

Comment: I changed it to that to shorten the query for this question, but I do need many properties.

Comment: We need more information. As *always*, your version of Postgres. Table definitions and cardinalities. Consider instruction in the [tag info for `postgresql-performance`](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplified query to make it readable:

```
SELECT *
FROM   "Follows" f
JOIN   "Users"   u ON f."followeeId" = u."id"
WHERE  f."followerId" = 169368
ORDER  BY f."createdAt" DESC
LIMIT  1000;
```

Your index `follows_followinglist_followerid_createdat_idx` looks good for the job. In Postgres 9.2+ it might get a bit faster if you append "followeeId" to the index - if and only if you can get an [index-only scan](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) out of this. Maybe not possible in your case.

```
CREATE INDEX follows_foo_idx ON "Follows"("followerId", "createdAt" DESC, "followeeId");
```

Generally, this query won't get lighning fast, since you have to fetch up to 1000 random rows from `"Users"`. The key to performance will be:

- Optimized table layout of "Users" to keep the table as small as possible, so fewer blocks have to be read and more of it can stay in cache.
- Plenty of RAM and cache settings accordingly if your table `"Users"` is big.

It would also help to cluster the `"Follows"` table from time to time. Details:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)