# PostgreSQL 9.4 query seems very slow

Tags: postgresql, performance, postgresql-9.4, query-performance

I'm experiencing a very long response time for a query returning a relatively small number of rows. It takes over three minutes to return ~1.3 million rows. I would assume it was an indexing problem except counting the rows takes almost no time at all.

Amazon AWS: It's running on an RDS t2.medium with a SSD (IOPS disabled) according to AWS console.

The table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ip_range_domains (
  ip_range_domain_id     BIGSERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  domain_id              BIGINT REFERENCES domains       NOT NULL,
  source_type_id         INTEGER REFERENCES source_types NOT NULL,
  low                    INET                            NOT NULL,
  high                   INET                            NOT NULL,
  auto_high_conf         BOOLEAN                         NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE,
  invalidation_reason_id INTEGER REFERENCES invalidation_reasons  DEFAULT NULL,
  invalidated_at         TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE              DEFAULT NULL,
  created_at             TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE     NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp
);
CREATE INDEX domain_id_btree ON ip_range_domains (domain_id);
```

I also created a hash index on it afterwards but it doesn't seem to have any effect.

The slow query:

```
SELECT * FROM ip_range_domains WHERE domain_id = 400266;
```

The query above took 224.9 Seconds:

```
=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip_range_domains WHERE domain_id = 400266;
  count  
---------
 1383530
```

The query above took 164 milliseconds to return:

```
=> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ip_range_domains;
  count   
----------
 23156869
```

The query above took 1.9 seconds to complete:

```
=> EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) SELECT * FROM ip_range_domains WHERE domain_id = 400266;
                                                                QUERY PLAN                                                                 
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on ip_range_domains  (cost=26398.17..282905.77 rows=1410288 width=55) (actual time=94.046..476.018 rows=1383530 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: (domain_id = 400266)
   Heap Blocks: exact=44000
   Buffers: shared hit=47783
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on test_index_9  (cost=0.00..26045.60 rows=1410288 width=0) (actual time=85.699..85.699 rows=1383530 loops=1)
         Index Cond: (domain_id = 400266)
         Buffers: shared hit=3783
 Planning time: 0.122 ms
 Execution time: 697.753 ms
(9 rows)
```

Postgres Version:

```
=> select version();
                                                    version                                                    
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PostgreSQL 9.4.4 on x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16), 64-bit
(1 row)
```

RDS Info:

```
db.t2.medium
IOPS: disabled
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly, this seems to be a misunderstanding. According to your query plan, you are retrieving `rows=1410288` and the query itself is ***not that slow***. It does not "take 224.9 seconds":

> ```
> Execution time: 697.753 ms
> ```

You *could* probably improve the performance of your query some more by increasing the locality of clustered data, i.e., `CLUSTER` (or `pg_repack`) your table based on your index `domain_id_btree` (that appears under the different name of `test_index_9` in your query plan). Details here:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

If you do that (arriving at a favorable physical order of rows) and if you mostly just `INSERT` rows (`UPDATE` / `DELETE` is rare) and since there seem to be *many* rows per `domain_id` you might also benefit from a [BRIN index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/brin-intro.html) (new in Postgres 9.5).

(It's remarkable that your current index is used *at all*, given that you retrieve ~ 6% of all rows. This indicates that your data is mostly clustered on `domain_id` already - or cost settings / statistics in your DB are inaccurate.)

But that's only going to reduce the 700 ms Postgres needs to execute the query. The rest of your reported `224.9 seconds` are spent somewhere else, probably ***network transfer*** and ***processing in client***.

Now, if you could retrieve fewer rows or less data per row ...

Comment: My EC2 instance and RDS instance were in different regions causing massive slowdowns. I didn't know that EXPLAIN was actually running the query in its entirety. Also, pg_repack is amazing. It's like everything I wished CLUSTER was.