# Does it make sense to store a couple of Boolean values as array?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, performance, datatypes, array

I have a table with five Boolean columns. In 90% plus of the rows, all the columns are null. (`False` is equivalent to `null` for me.)

Instead of having Boolean columns, I could have a single array column which contains an array of an enumerated custom datatype, and thereby store only the columns which are non-null.

I feel weird using arrays, but my coworker has pointed out to me that there isn't really a strong reason against using them, and we might actually see savings from using them since we aren't storing a bunch of empty columns.

Are there any downsides to using an array? Specifically: would they take up more space, take up more time to query, or prevent Postgres features (e.g. gin indexes) from being used?

Comment: Arrays will take much more space. Nulls in Postgres will need exactly 0 space under some circumstances.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

TL;DR: Do **not** use an array. Use individual `boolean` columns.

---

Your coworker may not be aware of actual storage requirements. Null storage is very cheap and efficient in Postgres. See:

- [Do nullable columns occupy additional space in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147130/939860)

A couple of `boolean` columns are also very cheap and efficient - nullable or not. Actually, just 5 `boolean` columns hardly matter for the row size at all - even if defined `NOT NULL`. 1 byte each, 5 bytes and no alignment restrictions. Hardly relevant. There are typically much more substantial things you can do to your row. (You should have provided your actual table definition.)

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Arrays have an overhead of **24 bytes**. Plus actual data. And handling is much less convenient and much more expensive:

- [Calculating and saving space in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7431468/939860)

This related answer has a detailed assessment for three relevant options:

1. separate `boolean` columns
2. an `integer` to encode up to 32 boolean values
3. a bitstring (`bit(n)` or `bit varying(n)`)

- [Is there any difference between integer and bit(n) data types for a bitmask?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9993552/939860)

Comment: Also the performance hit loading an array at runtime and fetching an element from it. Also the clarity hit by no longer having a dedicated, descriptive name for each boolean.

Answer (score 3):

In your case I think you could consider the use of a [Bit String Type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/datatype-bit.html) data type. 
For instance, something like:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable (
   booleans bit[5] default B'00000',
   ... other fields ... )
```

It is efficient in terms of memory and does not require the use of a complex type like a PostgreSQL array (actually *it is* a bit array), and more, you do not have to pay attention to the difference between false and null (and also you could set the entire field to a null value, if you need to).

Comment: Is there a way I can make a user defined type or something so that I don't have to remember what each bit means?

Comment: I think you could solve this problem at the application level, using as index to the array an enumeration or something like it according to your programming language.

Comment: Yeah, I could do that but it's always nicer if the sql is intuitive as well

Comment: Still, the type `bit(n)` has [`5 or 8 bytes overhead depending on the length of the string`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-bit.html). The total size of 5 `boolean NOT NULL` columns is 5 bytes. `bit(n)` is not efficient in terms of memory. The only possible advantage is that a single NULL can cover all 5 flags. 1 bit vs. 5 bit in the NULL bitmap. But that typically doesn't make any effective difference in storage.