# PostgreSQL indexing on bit string

Tags: postgresql, index, performance, postgresql-performance

What is the best way to create an index on a bit string column? Let's say I had the column of type `bit(4)` and I wanted to search for all entries that had had a specific bit set. So if I had the entries:

```
bitfield | ...
--------------
1001
1010
0110
0010
0000
```

If I was trying to search for all entries that `0010` set, I can easily do that. But can I use indexes to optimize the searching?

Comment: Oh, it was perfectly clear what you are trying to do, never mind my "funny" comment. Why did you remove almost all the content? It was a much more clear question before.

Comment: My critique was for the denormalization / use of bit strings and that this path does not lead to optimal design and results. I'm happy to remove my comment.

Comment: Postgres has a large arsenal of indexing options and index access methods. The best solution depends on the complete situation. A question like this must provide context: Postgres version (!), table definition, cardinalities, typical queries, and whatever else may be of relevance.

Answer (score 8):

First of all: it would be more efficient to store 4 bits of information as separate `boolean` columns - in every respect: easier to handle, easier to understand and change, easier to index, even smaller storage size! Closely related answer:

- [Does it make sense to store a couple of Boolean values as array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143766/does-it-make-sense-to-store-a-couple-of-boolean-values-as-array/143810#143810)

To **answer your question asked**: you can use a partial index like:

```
CREATE INDEX foo ON tbl (tbl_id)
WHERE bitfield & '0010' = '0010';
```

[**`&`** being the *bitwise AND* operator.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-bitstring.html)
`tbl_id` being the PK column. (The actual index column hardly matters here.)
In combination with a matching query:

```
SELECT *
FROM   tbl
WHERE  bitfield & '0010' = '0010';
```

But your question probably does not reflect your complete situation. There may be better options.

Comment: That was my initial implementation of indexing, but I was interested in seeing if there was a better way in doing so. Let's say that my bit string is 100 bits long and I wanted to be a be able to search for bit strings that had multiple bits set.

Comment: @TheDude: Please ask a question with all relevant information. [Follow instructions for Postgres performance questions here.](http://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info) Comments are not the place.