# How to efficiently store 672 bits of information in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I have a requirement that needs to store lots of bits and it's actually a time setting for every 15 minutes in a week (indicating if a user is free during that time).

So for one day we need: `60 minutes/ 15 = 4 * 24 hours = 96 bit`

And for a week, it will be: `96 * 7 = 672`

I was originally thinking that I could store this in 7 columns of `bigint[2]`,
each column representing a day and the first bigint of the array represening the bit from `00:00 to 12:00 (12 * 4 = 48bit)`.

And here is how I calculate the bigint:

```
  start_idx := extract(EPOCH FROM (first_half[1]::time - '00:00'::time))::integer/60/15;
  end_idx   := extract(EPOCH FROM (first_half[2]::time - '00:00'::time))::integer/60/15;
  -- RAISE NOTICE 'idx % %', start_idx, end_idx;

  WHILE start_idx < end_idx LOOP

   first_r := first_r | (1::bigint << start_idx);


   start_idx = start_idx + 1;
  END LOOP;
```

So the `start_idx` will be the result and contains all the bits from `00:00 to 12:00`.

But this is ugly because I have to separate the time setting into two parts and I just come across [this thread](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144463/postgresql-indexing-on-bit-string) that says that I should store the bits separately.

So I am not sure if I should use the array or if I should just create `672` columns of Boolean which I think is a bit crazy!

Comment: `bit(672)` maybe? Or an array of boolean? A `boolean[672]` will be a lot bigger than a `bit(672)` if that is a problem depends on how many rows you will have

Comment: `bit(672)` sounds good, I am thinking maybe 7 column of `bit(96)` is even better with bloom index. because of it more readable. but I am not sure about the performance

Comment: 1M rows, I guess storage should be fine, the problem is the query, giving a free time setting `query1`, I need to find out all the people who're free during that time

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name If you flesh that out a bit, it could well be an answer.

Comment: What are your requirements for retrieving/querying the data? Storing the time slots is only one part of the equation, retrieving the data could well be another issue.

Comment: @hot2use as I stated in the comments, I want to get all the rows that `contain` the same bits. if we store `bit(672)` then the query would be `select * from t where n & '0011'::bit(672) = '0011'::bit(672)`

Comment: How about DST ?