# Nullable columns or jsonb for storing user profile?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, schema, null, json

I'm deciding between using nullable fields or jsonb to store user profile. Initially, this would be used for contacts: `email` and `phone`. I anticipate that there may be other columns added later, such as `mobile` and `website`. Additionally, there may be other non-related fields, such as settings/preferences, saved searches, etc.

I've already decided that I don't want to use any form of key-value store (or any schema involving many-to-many relations) for this, unless there's an extremely good reason for it.

Pros of jsonb:

- Can store multiple values for each "column" if necessary
- Adding new field just needs JS coding and documentation

Cons of jsonb:

- Overhead of storing the "column" name as a string for each "row"
- Wonky to perform comparison queries (I think N/A to my usage scenario)
- Have to expect the unexpected

Anything else to add to this list of pros/cons? As much as I'd like to simply use nullable columns, I think it would be negligent to ignore jsonb - it seems like a compelling choice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use "best of both worlds". Implement every regular column you know of as dedicated column (with exact proper data type, possibly with NOT NULL / CHECK / PK / FK etc. constraints to enforce detailed rules, default values and comment for documentation) and add a "catch-all" `jsonb` column for very rare cases / later additions / highly volatile attributes that do not need any of the features mentioned above.

To be clear: "highly volatile" does not mean the value is updated a lot, which would clearly speak *against* any document type like `jsonb`, making updates more complex and expensive. It means the attribute per se (on the meta level) changes a lot (different names, rare and and pops in and out of existence over time or similar).

Most people underestimate how cheap NULL storage really is:

- [Do nullable columns occupy additional space in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12147130/939860)
- [Measure the size of a PostgreSQL table row](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23879/measure-the-size-of-a-postgresql-table-row/23933#23933)

Related:

- [Does it make sense to store a couple of Boolean values as array?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/143766/does-it-make-sense-to-store-a-couple-of-boolean-values-as-array/143810#143810)
- [Is there a name for this database schema of key values?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20759/is-there-a-name-for-this-database-structure)
- [jsonb and primary/foreign keys: which performs better in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27715835/939860)
- [Does JSONB make PostgreSQL arrays useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28934554/939860)