# Why are some count queries so slow?

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, execution-plan, query-performance

I have a table `users` with 2.6 millions of rows and `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users` takes 2 seconds to succeed, but request for table `stories` with 5.2 millions of rows takes ***more than an hour***.

Explains are pretty similar:

```
explain select count(*) from users;

 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=89417.87..89417.88 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Gather  (cost=89417.65..89417.86 rows=2 width=8)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=88417.65..88417.66 rows=1 width=8)
               ->  Parallel Seq Scan on users  (cost=0.00..85702.72 rows=1085972 width=0)
```

```
explain select count(*) from stories;

 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=428235.66..428235.67 rows=1 width=8)
   ->  Gather  (cost=428235.45..428235.66 rows=2 width=8)
         Workers Planned: 2
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=427235.45..427235.46 rows=1 width=8)
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using stories__is_permanently_deleted__idx on stories  (cost=0.43..421752.81 rows=2193057 width=0)
```

Postgres version:

```
                                                            version                                                            
 PostgreSQL 10.6 (Ubuntu 10.6-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.3.0-16ubuntu3) 7.3.0, 64-bit
```

Table definition of `stories`:

```
         Column          |  Type   | Collation | Nullable |                      Default                      | Storage  | Stats target | Description 
-------------------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------
 id                      | bigint  |           | not null | nextval('stories_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    |              | 
 rating                  | integer |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 number_of_pluses        | integer |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 number_of_minuses       | integer |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 title                   | text    |           | not null |                                                   | extended |              | 
 content_blocks          | jsonb   |           | not null |                                                   | extended |              | 
 created_at_timestamp    | bigint  |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 story_url               | text    |           | not null |                                                   | extended |              | 
 tags                    | jsonb   |           | not null |                                                   | extended |              | 
 number_of_comments      | integer |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 is_deleted              | boolean |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 is_rating_hidden        | boolean |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 has_mine_tag            | boolean |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 has_adult_tag           | boolean |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 is_longpost             | boolean |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 author_id               | bigint  |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 author_username         | text    |           | not null |                                                   | extended |              | 
 author_profile_url      | text    |           | not null |                                                   | extended |              | 
 author_avatar_url       | text    |           | not null |                                                   | extended |              | 
 community_link          | text    |           | not null |                                                   | extended |              | 
 community_name          | text    |           | not null |                                                   | extended |              | 
 comments_are_hot        | boolean |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 added_timestamp         | bigint  |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 last_update_timestamp   | bigint  |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 next_update_timestamp   | bigint  |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 task_taken_at_timestamp | bigint  |           | not null |                                                   | plain    |              | 
 is_permanently_deleted  | boolean |           | not null | false                                             | plain    |              | 
Indexes:
    "stories_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "stories__added_timestamp__idx" btree (added_timestamp)
    "stories__is_permanently_deleted__idx" btree (is_permanently_deleted)
    "stories__last_update_timestamp__idx" btree (last_update_timestamp)
    "stories__next_update_timestamp__idx" btree (next_update_timestamp)
    "stories__task_taken_at_timestamp__idx" btree (task_taken_at_timestamp)
```

Index definition:

```
     Index "public.stories__is_permanently_deleted__idx"
         Column         |  Type   |       Definition       | Storage 
------------------------+---------+------------------------+---------
 is_permanently_deleted | boolean | is_permanently_deleted | plain
btree, for table "public.stories"
```

***After*** reindexing (as advised):
`EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS) select count(*) from stories`:

```
 Finalize Aggregate  (cost=356218.22..356218.23 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=273577.971..273577.971 rows=1 loops=1)
   Buffers: shared hit=186467 read=65977 dirtied=24 written=1166
   ->  Gather  (cost=356218.01..356218.22 rows=2 width=8) (actual time=272647.858..273602.243 rows=3 loops=1)
         Workers Planned: 2
         Workers Launched: 2
         Buffers: shared hit=186467 read=65977 dirtied=24 written=1166
         ->  Partial Aggregate  (cost=355218.01..355218.02 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=272938.947..272938.948 rows=1 loops=3)
               Buffers: shared hit=186467 read=65977 dirtied=24 written=1166
               ->  Parallel Index Only Scan using stories__is_permanently_deleted__idx on stories  (cost=0.43..349741.33 rows=2190671 width=0) (actual time=0.386..271148.590 rows=1752497 loops=3)
                     Heap Fetches: 654818
                     Buffers: shared hit=186467 read=65977 dirtied=24 written=1166
 Planning time: 0.726 ms
 Execution time: 273602.447 ms
```

Comment: Your question should provide: Postgres version, table definition, index definition of `stories__is_permanently_deleted__idx`, physical index and table size, avg. row size of index and table, result from `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` instead of just `EXPLAIN`. These instructions have been given countless times. See tag [info of \[postgresql-performance\]](https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info).

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, provided more information in question.

Comment: It's in part due to the MVCC nature of PostgreSQL. One of the few times where a modern database architecture isn't as good as an older locking system. However, > 1hr for 5M records does seem excessive! Have you tried COUNT(primary_key_fields) or SELECT COUNT(1) FROM table;?

Comment: @Vérace, Tried count(primary_key), it was the same.

Comment: I'm just after doing a SELECT COUNT(1) FROM my_table (10M rows - SSD), and it came back in 600 ms (milliseconds)! Read carefully anything @ErwinBrandstetter has to say - he knows his stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you have a `Parallel Seq Scan` for `users`, you get a `Parallel Index Only Scan` for `stories` - which is typically *faster* than the sequential scan on the table.

If it's that slow, the obvious reason would be index bloat (or worse, index corruption).

**Recreate** the index and test again to see if that's so. If positive, investigate what bloats (or corrupts) your index. Corruption should be an extremely rare exception - unless you operate with faulty RAM / storage.

```
REINDEX INDEX stories__is_permanently_deleted__idx;
```

If you don't need *exact* counts, then there are *much* faster alternatives:

- [Fast way to discover the row count of a table in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7945274/939860)

---

**Aside:** reorder columns in `stories` like this to save ~ 20 bytes per row:

```
         Column          |  Type   
-------------------------+---------
 id                      | bigint  
 created_at_timestamp    | bigint  
 added_timestamp         | bigint  
 last_update_timestamp   | bigint  
 next_update_timestamp   | bigint  
 task_taken_at_timestamp | bigint  
 author_id               | bigint
 rating                  | integer 
 number_of_pluses        | integer 
 number_of_minuses       | integer 
 number_of_comments      | integer  
 is_deleted              | boolean 
 is_rating_hidden        | boolean 
 has_mine_tag            | boolean 
 has_adult_tag           | boolean 
 is_longpost             | boolean 
 comments_are_hot        | boolean 
 is_permanently_deleted  | boolean
 author_username         | text    
 author_profile_url      | text    
 author_avatar_url       | text    
 community_link          | text    
 community_name          | text    
 title                   | text    
 story_url               | text    
 content_blocks          | jsonb   
 tags                    | jsonb
```

See:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Comment: Storage should be OK, cause it's a new server and I checked S.M.A.R.T. about a month ago. 

Just tried to make seq scan by disabling index scan `set enable_indexscan = off;` and it counted all the stories in 12 minutes, not good, but obviously better. 

I'll try to recreate index and test. 

Can it be caused by stories being added constantly? 

Cause it's a parser and now it inserts ~3 new story per second.

Comment: Yes, I know about the fast ways, but I also need to count number of items in index like `select count(*) from stories where some_column < some_value`. Thanks for help.

Comment: @devalone: Yes, unceasing insert activity might well account for index bloat. Unfavorable write patterns might result in sub-optimal index. Aggressive autovacuum setting for the table and occasional reindex might help. Remarkable: one hardly gets index-only scans for tables with that kind of write load since the visibility map can't catch up ...

Comment: Yes, reindexing helps, after it, counting takes 333 seconds(5 minutes) which is still not good, but way better than it used to be. So I need to dig in autovacuum settings? Thanks again.