# Improve COUNT, JOIN and GROUP BY query performance

Tags: postgresql, query-performance, query, postgresql-performance

I am trying to get the count per group for a given user and wrote the query below. The execution plan looks fine. However, in some cases, the user has around 10k articles and with a bit of load the queries start to be very slow and CPU usage goes up.

How can I improve the performances of the query below?

I am using PostgreSQL 11.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS occurences, seller_nickname AS value, seller_id AS id 
FROM data.saved_articles 
JOIN aggregated.offers USING (offer_id) 
WHERE user_id = 406943491 
GROUP BY seller_nickname, seller_id;
```

Example result set:

```
occurences    value     id
1             "nick1"   id-1
8             "nick2"   id-2
```

Query plan:

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=50262.89..51401.41 rows=9427 width=23) (actual time=58.418..68.209 rows=3527 loops=1)
  Output: count(*), offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
  Group Key: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
  Buffers: shared hit=17448 dirtied=75
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=50262.89..51248.22 rows=7856 width=23) (actual time=58.413..66.732 rows=4549 loops=1)
        Output: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id, (PARTIAL count(*))
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=37116 dirtied=150
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=49262.86..49341.42 rows=3928 width=23) (actual time=45.467..46.616 rows=1516 loops=3)
              Output: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id, PARTIAL count(*)
              Group Key: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
              Buffers: shared hit=37116 dirtied=150
              Worker 0: actual time=31.676..32.206 rows=726 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=4337 dirtied=16
              Worker 1: actual time=46.740..48.138 rows=1841 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=15331 dirtied=59
              ->  Sort  (cost=49262.86..49272.68 rows=3928 width=15) (actual time=45.458..45.738 rows=3073 loops=3)
                    Output: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
                    Sort Key: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 436kB
                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 110kB
                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 314kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=37116 dirtied=150
                    Worker 0: actual time=31.666..31.759 rows=1077 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=4337 dirtied=16
                    Worker 1: actual time=46.732..47.088 rows=3811 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=15331 dirtied=59
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=229.92..49028.37 rows=3928 width=15) (actual time=0.407..35.412 rows=3073 loops=3)
                          Output: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
                          Inner Unique: true
                          Buffers: shared hit=37086 dirtied=150
                          Worker 0: actual time=0.096..28.787 rows=1077 loops=1
                            Buffers: shared hit=4322 dirtied=16
                          Worker 1: actual time=0.103..36.065 rows=3811 loops=1
                            Buffers: shared hit=15316 dirtied=59
                          ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on data.saved_articles  (cost=229.49..21594.86 rows=3928 width=4) (actual time=0.368..1.219 rows=3073 loops=3)
                                Output: saved_articles.offer_id
                                Recheck Cond: (saved_articles.user_id = 406943491)
                                Heap Blocks: exact=67
                                Buffers: shared hit=178
                                Worker 0: actual time=0.056..0.384 rows=1077 loops=1
                                  Buffers: shared hit=12
                                Worker 1: actual time=0.061..1.154 rows=3811 loops=1
                                  Buffers: shared hit=59
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pk_saved_articles_user_id_offer_id  (cost=0.00..227.13 rows=9427 width=0) (actual time=0.941..0.941 rows=9220 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (saved_articles.user_id = 406943491)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=40
                          ->  Index Scan using pk_offers_offer_id on aggregated.offers  (cost=0.43..6.98 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=9220)
                                Output: offers.offer_id, offers.seller_id, offers.seller_nickname, offers.title, offers.condition, offers.ends_at, offers.current_price, offers.buynow_price, offers.category_id, offers.category_name_fr, offers.category_name_de, offers.category_name_it, offers.created_at, offers.updated_at, offers.bid_count, offers.quantity, offers.increment, offers.offer_type
                                Index Cond: (offers.offer_id = saved_articles.offer_id)
                                Buffers: shared hit=36908 dirtied=150
                                Worker 0: actual time=0.026..0.026 rows=1 loops=1077
                                  Buffers: shared hit=4310 dirtied=16
                                Worker 1: actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=3811
                                  Buffers: shared hit=15257 dirtied=59
Planning Time: 0.274 ms
Execution Time: 68.714 ms
```

To improve performance, I could maybe limit the result set to 100 per group.

Tables and indexes:

```
CREATE TABLE aggregated.offers (
    offer_id integer NOT NULL,
    seller_id integer NOT NULL,
    seller_nickname character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    title character varying(60) NOT NULL
);

ALTER TABLE aggregated.offers
    ADD CONSTRAINT pk_offers_offer_id PRIMARY KEY (offer_id);

CREATE INDEX idx_offers_seller_id ON aggregated.offers (seller_id);

CREATE TABLE data.saved_articles (
    user_id integer NOT NULL,
    offer_id integer NOT NULL,
    created_at timestamp with time zone NOT NULL,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone,
    CONSTRAINT pk_saved_articles_user_id_offer_id PRIMARY KEY (user_id, offer_id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_saved_articles_offer_id FOREIGN KEY (offer_id)
        REFERENCES aggregated.offers (offer_id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE INDEX idx_saved_articles_offer_id ON data.saved_articles (offer_id);
```

**EDIT:**

Starting with the easiest approach, I ran the the `VACUUM` and created an index:

```
EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, COSTS, VERBOSE, BUFFERS)
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS occurences, seller_nickname AS value, seller_id AS id 
 FROM data.saved_articles 
 JOIN aggregated.offers USING (offer_id) 
 WHERE user_id = 406943491 
 GROUP BY seller_nickname, seller_id
```

However, it did not seem to have any major impact.

Plan:

```
Finalize GroupAggregate  (cost=54772.66..56138.73 rows=11312 width=23) (actual time=54.118..61.137 rows=3527 loops=1)
  Output: count(*), offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
  Group Key: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
  Buffers: shared hit=17925
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=54772.66..55954.92 rows=9426 width=23) (actual time=54.112..61.691 rows=4482 loops=1)
        Output: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id, (PARTIAL count(*))
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=38070
        ->  Partial GroupAggregate  (cost=53772.64..53866.90 rows=4713 width=23) (actual time=40.581..41.995 rows=1494 loops=3)
              Output: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id, PARTIAL count(*)
              Group Key: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
              Buffers: shared hit=38070
              Worker 0: actual time=43.304..45.268 rows=1882 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=16389
              Worker 1: actual time=24.626..25.086 rows=603 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=3756
              ->  Sort  (cost=53772.64..53784.42 rows=4713 width=15) (actual time=40.571..40.921 rows=3073 loops=3)
                    Output: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
                    Sort Key: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
                    Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 437kB
                    Worker 0:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 323kB
                    Worker 1:  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 76kB
                    Buffers: shared hit=38070
                    Worker 0: actual time=43.293..43.759 rows=3969 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=16389
                    Worker 1: actual time=24.616..24.709 rows=913 loops=1
                      Buffers: shared hit=3756
                    ->  Nested Loop  (cost=216.53..53485.09 rows=4713 width=15) (actual time=0.457..30.793 rows=3073 loops=3)
                          Output: offers.seller_nickname, offers.seller_id
                          Inner Unique: true
                          Buffers: shared hit=38040
                          Worker 0: actual time=0.191..32.516 rows=3969 loops=1
                            Buffers: shared hit=16374
                          Worker 1: actual time=0.171..22.287 rows=913 loops=1
                            Buffers: shared hit=3741
                          ->  Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on data.saved_articles  (cost=216.10..24104.73 rows=4713 width=4) (actual time=0.371..1.275 rows=3073 loops=3)
                                Output: saved_articles.offer_id
                                Recheck Cond: (saved_articles.user_id = 406943491)
                                Heap Blocks: exact=60
                                Buffers: shared hit=166
                                Worker 0: actual time=0.075..1.420 rows=3969 loops=1
                                  Buffers: shared hit=66
                                Worker 1: actual time=0.059..0.344 rows=913 loops=1
                                  Buffers: shared hit=12
                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on pk_saved_articles_user_id_offer_id  (cost=0.00..213.27 rows=11312 width=0) (actual time=0.929..0.929 rows=9220 loops=1)
                                      Index Cond: (saved_articles.user_id = 406943491)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=28
                          ->  Index Only Scan using tmp_id on aggregated.offers  (cost=0.43..6.23 rows=1 width=19) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=9220)
                                Output: offers.offer_id, offers.seller_id, offers.seller_nickname
                                Index Cond: (offers.offer_id = saved_articles.offer_id)
                                Heap Fetches: 9129
                                Buffers: shared hit=37874
                                Worker 0: actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=1 loops=3969
                                  Buffers: shared hit=16308
                                Worker 1: actual time=0.023..0.023 rows=1 loops=913
                                  Buffers: shared hit=3729
Planning Time: 0.275 ms
Execution Time: 63.720 ms
```

Since I need to run the same query on another column, I will not touch the PK and instead to try to have `seller_nickname` on a different table to be able to add it after the aggregation.

Comment: Is 69 ms an accurate example of the "very slow" query which needs to be improved? How much faster than 69 ms does it need to be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query seems to perform ok already. Some ideas to squeeze out faster times:

#### Index-only scans for `aggregated.offers`

`seller_nickname` seems to be functionally dependent on `seller_id`. It is more expensive to read and group by a `varchar(30)` additionally, than to base that on just an `integer`. Cutting `seller_nickname` out of the base query should make it faster. Then you can add `seller_id` to the PK with an `INCLUDE` clause to get a covering index and very fast index-only scans on `aggregated.offers`:

```
ALTER TABLE aggregated.offers
  DROP CONSTRAINT pk_offers_offer_id 
, ADD  CONSTRAINT pk_offers_offer_id PRIMARY KEY (offer_id) INCLUDE (seller_id);
```

Since `offer_id` and `seller_id` are both `int4` we hit a local optimum. See:

- [Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Faster query:

```
SELECT count(*) AS occurrences, o.seller_id AS id  -- note occurrences with "rr"
FROM   data.saved_articles a
JOIN   aggregated.offers   o USING (offer_id) 
WHERE  a.user_id = 406943491 
GROUP  BY o.seller_id;
```

If you really need to include `seller_nickname` in the result, add it *after* the aggregation from a lookup table. Assuming a table `seller` (which you would typically have), ideally with an index on `(seller_id, seller_nickname)` for another index-only scan:

```
SELECT ao.*, s.seller_nickname
FROM  (  -- query from above
   SELECT count(*) AS occurrences, o.seller_id AS id
   FROM   data.saved_articles a
   JOIN   aggregated.offers   o USING (offer_id) 
   WHERE  a.user_id = 406943491 
   GROUP  BY o.seller_id
   ) ao
LEFT   JOIN data.seller s USING (seller_id);
```

Should still be faster, especially with more than a few rows per seller in the result.

Alternatively, you *could* just add `seller_nickname` to the PK index in the `INCLUDE` clause to speed up your original query. *Or* leave the PK untouched and add another index on `(offer_id, seller_id, seller_nickname)`. But while including the integer column `seller_id` is very light-weight on the PK index and typically has hardly any downsides (do read the linked answer!), adding another `varchar(30)` is more costly. And you'll want to keep the PK index snappy for other purposes.

#### `autovacuum` for `data.saved_articles`

Your PK index on `(user_id, offer_id)` seems perfect for the task. However, I see a `Bitmap Index Scan on pk_saved_articles_user_id_offer_id` with `rows=9220`, followed by a `Parallel Bitmap Heap Scan on data.saved_articles` with `rows=3073` - swallowing ~ 40 % of the query time.

No index-only scan. And only a third of the index tuples produce a heap tuple.
That indicates problems with autovacuum: outdated visibility map and lots of dead index tuples. If possible (takes an exclusive lock on the table, does concurrent workload allow it?), try:

```
VACUUM FULL ANALYZE data.saved_articles;
```

Or use `CLUSTER` to cluster rows with the same `user_id` in physical storage.

```
CLUSTER data.saved_articles USING pk_saved_articles_user_id_offer_id;
ANALYZE data.saved_articles;
```

Then, even if write load on `saved_articles` prevents index-only scans, fewer blocks have to be read from the heap. But it's a one-time effect deteriorating over time.

Either way, if that improves performance, set up more aggressive `autovacuum` settings for table `data.saved_articles` and / or consider using [`pg_repack`](https://github.com/reorg/pg_repack) or [`pg_squeeze`](https://github.com/cybertec-postgresql/pg_squeeze) - which can replace `VACUUM FULL` / `CLUSTER` and work under concurrent load.

Related:

- [Configuring PostgreSQL for read performance](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/42290/configuring-postgresql-for-read-performance/43142#43142)

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. A few points, I did not get.
What do you mean _after_ the aggregation, in another query? Do i need to add the `seller_nickname` in the covering index?

If I need to run the same query but for other columns (same table) to get their count, should I just add them in the `INCLUDE` clause?

Comment: I ran `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE data.saved_articles;` and re-ran the `EXPLAIN` but without any noticeable differences.

Comment: @nss: I added some more above about indices and dealing with `seller_nickname`. This answer is tailored to the question, didn't take *other columns* into account. Either way, NO, don't `INCLUDE` more columns to the PK index.

Comment: @nss Did the query plan change after `VACUUM FULL ANALYZE data.saved_articles;`? Did you see index-only scans? Did you run the query a couple of times to saturate cache again?

Comment: I updated my question with (some) of your suggestions